# Why is document.all falsy?

Tags: javascript, dom

`document.all` is a non-primitive object in the DOM that is falsy.

For example, this code doesn't do anything:

```
if (document.all) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Modern browsers don't implement this outdated thing any more. It's a IE "standard", Opera also "shims" it.

Comment: @Nanne the question is: can someone explain, why the code does nothing. If it isn't implemented, if will be false and nothing will happen. So I do think, it is answer.

Comment: But the question also stated that we are dealing with a non-null object? Maybe I read that wrong, but I assumed that means in the test it was there, but just didn't trigger?

Comment: @Nanne: OK, I understood the question now. I've added another answer.

Comment: There's a good tl;dr explanation in Kyle Simpson's book about this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#falsy-objects (scroll down to the 'Why?!' heading).

Comment: Chrome 75 in 2019 still has `document.all == null`. Why? What is the point of still maintaining this?

Answer (score 131):

**Disclaimer:** [I’m the guy who tweeted the question that led to this thread :)](http://twitter.com/mathias/status/195818066016354305) It was a question I would ask and answer in my [Front-Trends](http://2012.front-trends.com/) talk. I wrote that tweet 5 minutes before going on stage.

---

The question I was asking is the following.

The ECMAScript spec [defines `ToBoolean()` as follows](http://es5.github.com/x9.html#x9.2):

[image: ToBoolean(condition), slide from my Front-Trends 2012 talk]

As you can see, all non-primitive objects (i.e. all objects that aren’t a boolean, a number, a string, `undefined`, or `null`) are truthy as per the spec. However, in the DOM, there is one exception to this — a DOM object that is falsy. Do you know which one that is?

The answer is `document.all`. [The HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-all) says:

> The `all` attribute must return an `HTMLAllCollection` rooted at the `Document` node, whose filter matches all elements.
>
> The object returned for all has several unusual behaviors:
>
> The user agent must act as if the `ToBoolean()` operator in JavaScript
>   converts the object returned for `all` to the `false` value.
>
> The user agent must act as if, for the purposes of the `==` and `!=`
>   operators in JavaScript, the object returned for `all` is equal to the
>   `undefined` value.
>
> The user agent must act such that the `typeof` operator in JavaScript
>   returns the string `'undefined'` when applied to the object returned for
>   `all`.
>
> These requirements are a willful violation of the JavaScript
>   specification current at the time of writing (ECMAScript edition 5).
>   The JavaScript specification requires that the `ToBoolean()` operator
>   convert all objects to the `true` value, and does not have provisions
>   for objects acting as if they were `undefined` for the purposes of
>   certain operators. This violation is motivated by a desire for
>   compatibility with two classes of legacy content: one that uses the
>   presence of `document.all` as a way to detect legacy user agents, and
>   one that only supports those legacy user agents and uses the
>   `document.all` object without testing for its presence first.

So, `document.all` is the only official exception to this ECMAScript rule. (In Opera, `document.attachEvent` etc. are falsy too, but that’s not specced anywhere.)

The above text explains why this was done. But here’s an example code snippet that’s very common on old web pages, and that will illustrate this further:

```
if (document.all) {
  // code that uses `document.all`, for ancient browsers
} else if (document.getElementById) {
  // code that uses `document.getElementById`, for “modern” browsers
}
```

Basically, for a long time `document.all` was used in this way to detect old browsers. Because `document.all` is tested first though, more modern browsers that offer both properties, would still end up in the `document.all` code path. In modern browsers, we’d prefer to use `document.getElementById`, of course, but since most browsers still have `document.all` (for other backwards compatibility reasons) the `else` would never be accessed if `document.all` was truthy. Had the code been written differently, this wouldn’t be a problem:

```
if (document.getElementById) {
  // code that uses `document.getElementById`, for “modern” browsers
} else if (document.all) {
  // code that uses `document.all`, for ancient browsers
}
```

But sadly, a lot of existing code does it the other way around.

The simplest fix for this problem is to simply make `document.all` be falsy in browsers that still mimic it.

Comment: Quite involved answer for an obsolete feature.

Comment: @adrian Welcome to the Web, where everything is complicated because of legacy features :)

Comment: But in Oct'17 they had this notice removed, though the behavior remains the same up until this very day...

Comment: And so we have https://mariusschulz.com/blog/nullish-coalescing-the-operator-in-typescript#compiled-output-checking-for-null-and-undefined
smh

Comment: Interesting. I think this was because document.all was not ever implemented by Netscape. You *had* to use document.getElementById. And for IE you *had* to use document.all. Therefore there was no 'newer' or 'older' way to do it, they were just competing browsers, so there was no particular reason to have document.getElementById condition first. At some point (possibly when Chrome came along?) document.all started working again, but only kind of since you could no longer test for it...

Answer (score 24):

### ES2019 Update

There is now an [[[IsHTMLDDA]] internal slot](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot) for objects:

> An [[IsHTMLDDA]] internal slot may exist on implementation-defined objects. Objects with an [[IsHTMLDDA]] internal slot behave like `undefined` in the ToBoolean and Abstract Equality Comparison abstract operations and when used as an operand for the `typeof` operator.

The HTML Standard has also been updated to add that internal slot for objects that implement the [`HTMLAllCollection` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlallcollection):

> Objects that implement the HTMLAllCollection interface are legacy platform objects with an additonal [[Call]] internal method described in the section below. They also have an [[IsHTMLDDA]] internal slot.

---

The reason for this madness is specified in this note in the HTML Standard:

> These special behaviors are motivated by a desire for compatibility with two classes of legacy content: one that uses the presence of `document.all` as a way to detect legacy user agents, and one that only supports those legacy user agents and uses the `document.all` object without testing for its presence first.

So basically the standard wants to be compatible with these two types of code:

- Code that checks if it is running inside Internet Explorer to use its non-standard features, like `document.all` and Activex;

  ```js
  if (document.all) {
      useActiveXStuff();
  }
  ```
- Code that assumes it's running inside Internet Explorer and uses `document.all`.

  ```js
  document.all["my-button"].onclick = function () {
      alert("hi");
  };
  ```

Comment: Seems like [DDA stands for “Document Dot All”](https://zenn.dev/qnighy/articles/1d96f2c0c662f6#:~:text=%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%20DDA%20%E3%82%82%20Document%20Dot%20All%20%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)

Answer (score 8):

Modern browsers don't implement this outdated thing any more. It was introduced by IE, but most of the others "shim" it to be compatible.

To make browser detection possible (back in the old days you could tell IE apart from NN by testing for `document.all`) while supporting document.all syntax, other browsers made the "weird" implementation that `typeof document.all` returns undefined.

```
Opera> document.all
// prints the array-like object
Opera> typeof document.all
"undefined"
Opera> Boolean(document.all)
false
```

Before FF dropped support for it, it also showed weird behaviour as stated in [this message](http://old.nabble.com/FF-document.all-boolean-conversion%3A-please-vote-for-Rhino-patch-allowing-to-support-it-correctly-p14799030.html). You may find more internals in [Mozilla bug #412247](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412247).

There is also a [very long thread](http://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/advanced_search?keywords=typeof+document.all&hdr-1-name=subject&hdr-1-query=&hdr-2-name=from&hdr-2-query=&hdr-3-name=message-id&hdr-3-query=&period_month=&period_year=&index-grp=Public__FULL&index-type=t&type-index=public-html&resultsperpage=100&sortby=date-asc) in the W3C mailing list archive, beginning with http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Jun/0546.html

Answer (score 8):

In short, it's to make BOTH of these code samples work. Browsers have to do this so that old web pages will continue to work.

## Sample 1

```
// Internet Explorer
if (document.all) {
    useActiveX()
}
// Netscape Navigator
else {
    useOldButStillWorkingCode()
}
```

## Sample 2

```
document.all.output.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!'
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers already give a good explanation of why `document.all` behaves the way it does.

However, I was very curious to know more about the historical perspective. Where does `document.all` come from and why do modern browsers support it to this day?

So, I did some research to learn more about it, and here's what I found.

`document.all` was originally introduced in Internet Explorer 4. It's main use was to access elements by ID, like this:

```js
var element = document.all[id]
```

Later, the W3C standardized `document.getElementById` as a way to get elements by their ID.

However, since IE had the biggest market share for many years, many websites just kept using `document.all` without testing for it.

Some of these websites were quite popular and they would break in browsers other than IE.

Therefore, there started being discussions about adding support for `document.all` in other browsers so that websites using `document.all` would work in those browsers.

Just to give you some examples of what was being discussed, here are two discussions from bugzilla:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74201
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154589

So, in the end, other browsers started implementing `document.all`.

However, since websites were using `document.all` to detect IE using `if` statements like this one:

```js
if (document.all) {
  // Use proprietary Internet Explorer APIs
}
```

To prevent other browsers from being misdetected as Internet Explorer, the W3C standardized `document.all` as a falsy object that behaves like undefined.

So, as of 2023, `document.all` is still supported in all major browsers. Why you might ask? Probably because they want old websites to work.

I actually made a 2 minute YouTube video about `document.all` and its history, so if you're curious about that, check it out: https://youtu.be/KFasyUpmoss

[image: document.all]