# In JavaScript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an object with a member added conditionally.
The simple approach is:

```
var a = {};
if (someCondition)
    a.b = 5;
```

Now, I would like to write a more idiomatic code. I am trying:

```
a = {
    b: (someCondition? 5 : undefined)
};
```

But now, `b` is a member of `a` whose value is `undefined`. This is not the desired result.

Is there a handy solution?

**Update**

I seek for a solution that could handle the general case with several members.

```
a = {
  b: (conditionB? 5 : undefined),
  c: (conditionC? 5 : undefined),
  d: (conditionD? 5 : undefined),
  e: (conditionE? 5 : undefined),
  f: (conditionF? 5 : undefined),
  g: (conditionG? 5 : undefined),
 };
```

Comment: Not sure there's a such thing as idiomatic JavaScript...

Comment: Does it actually matter? If you never defined `a.b`, retrieving `a.b` would return `undefined` anyway.

Comment: @Teemu: It could matter when the `in` operator is used.

Comment: @amnotiam Oops... that's true, seems that I wasn't thinking all aspects...

Comment: Well, you've taken a step closer to telling us what you're actually needing. Now perhaps you'll take it the rest of the way, and describe what `conditionB-G` actually represent. Perhaps a loop would be helpful?

Comment: `conditionB-G` are independent conditions which are not known a priori.

Comment: What is an  unknown condition? Is it eval'd into the code?

Comment: I mean that I look for a general pattern to write the code. This pattern should not depend on the conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm saying the pattern could depend on the type of condition. If you want to know if there's a way to use object literal syntax that excludes some of the literal properties being defined, then no there isn't. Depending on the type of condition, your best bet may just be to put your `if` in a loop.

Comment: There is no way to have conditional properties in literal objects for now, but I wish they add it in ES7, this could be very handy especially in server side programming!

Comment: If anyone finds this question but was looking for conditional computed properties instead of just conditional properties, head to this question and vote to reopen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214748/how-to-conditionally-add-a-computed-property-name-to-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In pure Javascript, I cannot think of anything more idiomatic than your first code snippet.

If, however, using the jQuery library is not out of the question, then [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) should meet your requirements because, as the documentation says:

> Undefined properties are not copied.

Therefore, you can write:

```
var a = $.extend({}, {
    b: conditionB ? 5 : undefined,
    c: conditionC ? 5 : undefined,
    // and so on...
});
```

And obtain the results you expect (if `conditionB` is `false`, then `b` will not exist in `a`).

Comment: does null work the same way ? or does it have to be undefined ?

Comment: This is actually a wrong answer, because it uses jQuery and this ternary condition won't remove a property from an object, this just would set a property as undefined. See @lagistos answer for the correct way to do this,

Answer (score 2211):

I think @InspiredJW did it with ES5, and as @trincot pointed out, using es6 is a better approach.  But we can add a bit more sugar, by using the spread operator, and logical AND short circuit evaluation:

```
const a = {
   ...(someCondition && {b: 5})
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure this is correct, the [proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md) states `Null/Undefined Are Ignored`, it does not say `false` is ignored. Transpilers may allow this through at present, but is it compliant? The following ought to be `{...someCondition ? {b: 5} : null}` but isn't as compact.

Comment: Sorry, upon digging further. The behaviour of the spec _does_ allow this syntax - although, not due to any sort of special case handling for false booleans in the same way `null` or `undefined` are handled - just due to some low-level language semantics converting primitives to objects. Anyway, it's just the proposal _summary_ that's a bit confusing - the proposal is fine and allows this syntax. Phew!

Comment: I asked if this was valid to the people who made spread proposal and they said this is fine. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45 , cc @BenjaminDobell

Comment: @AlanH spread operator is like a shorthand of `Object.assign` and have lower precedence than the && operator. It ignore value without property (boolean, null, undefined, number), and add all properties of the object after the `...` in place.
remember the `&&` operator return the right value if true, or false otherwise.  so if `someCondition` is true, `{b : 5}` will be passed to the `...` operator, resulting in adding the property `b` to `a` with value `5`. is `someCondition` is false, `false`will be passed to the `...` operator. resulting in nothing added. it's clever. I love it.

Comment: Great answer, but putting the condition and the resulting object being spread into parentheses will greatly improve readability of this example. Not everyone remembers JS operator precedence by heart.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud what do you mean? can you write an example of that syntax? and if you can, please explain why it is more readable in your opinion. i'm curious :)

Comment: I mean: `...(someCondition && {b: 5})`.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud Aw, i thought you were talking about something else. but yeah, wrapping it in parens does make it a bit more readable. it reminds me of [this article](http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html)

Comment: This is good.  But for chains, there is an issue, you can use hoek.reach to fix it though.`const hoek = require("hoek");`
`let foo = { a: { b: { c:"foo string", d:false, e:true } } };`
`let retval1 = {`
`...(hoek.reach(foo, 'a.b.c') && {thing1: foo.a.b.c}),`
`...(hoek.reach(foo, 'a.b.d') && {thing3: foo.a.b.d}),//Not OK for false`
`...(hoek.reach(foo, 'a.b.e') && {thing2: foo.a.b.e}),`
`...(hoek.reach(foo, 'a.z.e') && {thing2: foo.a.z.e})//OK for non-existance`
`};`

Comment: The only other issue is you can't use this for false booleans.

Comment: @ggb667 yes you can, with double negation

`...(!!someFalsyCondition && {b: 5})`

Comment: Be careful, this doesn't work with arrays too. Spread operator throws when spreading null on arrays. https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/687

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If `someCondition` is `undefined`, I get an `Uncaught ReferencError`. I'm verifying this in Chrome's console.

Comment: as @CyrilCHAPON pointed out, it does not work for arrays - gave my some head scratches. Instead do this: `const a = [...(maybeArray || [])]`

Comment: Quick question, sometimes this syntax does not work on browser consoles. I've tried on chrome, it works but my co-worker's chrome it doesn't work. On Microsoft Edge, it doesn't work. Should I be worried?

Comment: @jake you should worry only if you don't compile your javascript before deployment with tools like babels and don't implements the polyfills for the ES6 feature you are using in your code, but you should worry about any ES6 feature if that's the case, not this in particular.

Comment: If you go to chrome console now and you try running this solution without defining `someCondition` you will get an error.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Just want to also mention that you can omit the parens.
`{...true && {a: 'a'}}`

Comment: It’s better to make the intent more explicit with `({ ...(someCondition ? { b: 5 } : {}) })`; e.g. this won’t work if `someCondition === document.all`, or with other falsy values which have own properties (which the specification doesn’t prohibit).

Comment: @inertia Make sure you force the object literal to be in expression context. `{}` is a block if not in expression context, so typing `{ ...(someCondition && { b: 5 }) }` in the console won’t work for some browsers, unless you wrap the object literal in parentheses. See [Why does `{} == null` give a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53306680/4642212).

Comment: It is not safe, '...' only available for objec,so you will get error like: ```Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)
``` if 'someCondition' return falsy.

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/45 , The comment which justifies the above solution, have mentioned `Object.assign will treat all primitives as same` in that case , it treats `string` by splitting the characters. 

Which is kind of confusing as string comes under primitive 

{ ...{ true & 'abc'}} = { '0': a , '1': b, '2': c}

Comment: for typescript users: ...(someCondition && {b: 5})as any

Answer (score 345):

```
const obj = {
   ...(condition) && {someprop: propvalue},
   ...otherprops
}
```

Live Demo:

```js
const obj = {
  ...(true) && {someprop: 42},
  ...(false) && {nonprop: "foo"},
  ...({}) && {tricky: "hello"},
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What does this answer add to [Jamie Hill's answer from 2 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/40560953#40560953)?

Comment: if cond does not match than this will return undefined.

Comment: No, if the condition is false nothing will be added. The spread syntax will get an object of the some prop and destruct it if the condition is true or false and then it will add nothing

Comment: This is not a valid syntax. Spread can only be used with iterables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903050/babel-7-and-webpack-4-not-working-for-conditional-spread-operation-in-arrayshor/55396142#55396142

Comment: It's valid and you can try it

Comment: Short explanation goes like this:
"..." spread operator deconstructs the object literal and adds it to "obj"
e.g. in this case
...(true) && {someprop: 42}, the whole term that is to be deconstructed is "(true) && {someprop: 42}", in this case the boolean is true and the term just yields {someprop:42} which is then deconstructed and added into obj.
if the boolean is false instead, then the term will just be false, and nothing will be deconstructed and added into obj

Comment: I am getting `Type '{ ... }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)`

Comment: _Prettier_ auto-formats it to `...(true && {someprop: 42}),`

Answer (score 166):

I suggest the following:

```js
const a = {
   ...(someCondition? {b: 5}: {})
}
```

Comment: This answer is awesome! Made a gist with an example of conditionally adding authorization field to fetch params for POST here: https://gist.github.com/mattlockyer/3dac7c9618ac98d16b046e32c364899d

Comment: This is indeed more readable than the shorter `someCondition && {b:5}`

Answer (score 122):

With EcmaScript2015 you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(a, conditionB ? { b: 1 } : null,
                 conditionC ? { c: 2 } : null,
                 conditionD ? { d: 3 } : null);
```

```js
var a, conditionB, conditionC, conditionD;
conditionC = true;
a = {};
Object.assign(a, conditionB ? { b: 1 } : null,
                 conditionC ? { c: 2 } : null,
                 conditionD ? { d: 3 } : null);

console.log(a);
```

Some remarks:

- `Object.assign` modifies the first argument in-place, but it also returns the updated object: so you can use this method in a bigger expression that further manipulates the object.
- Instead of `null` you could pass `undefined` or `{}`, with the same result. You could even provide `0` instead, because [primitive values are wrapped, and `Number` has no own enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Primitives_will_be_wrapped_to_objects).

#### Even more concise

Taking the second point further, you could shorten it as follows (as @Jamie has pointed out), as falsy values have no own enumerable properties (`false`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `''`, except [`document.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy)):

```
Object.assign(a, conditionB && { b: 1 },
                 conditionC && { c: 2 },
                 conditionD && { d: 3 });
```

```js
var a, conditionB, conditionC, conditionD;
conditionC = "this is truthy";
conditionD = NaN; // falsy
a = {};
Object.assign(a, conditionB && { b: 1 },
                 conditionC && { c: 2 },
                 conditionD && { d: 3 });
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 65):

**Perfomance test**

**Classic** approach

```
const a = {};
if (someCondition)
    a.b = 5;
```

**VS**

**spread operator** approach

```
const a2 = {
   ...(someCondition && {b: 5})
}
```

***Results*:**

The classic approach is much faster, so take in consideration that the syntax sugaring is slower.

> testClassicConditionFulfilled(); // ~ 234.9ms
> testClassicConditionNotFulfilled(); // ~493.1ms
> testSpreadOperatorConditionFulfilled(); // ~2649.4ms
> testSpreadOperatorConditionNotFulfilled(); // ~2278.0ms

```js
function testSpreadOperatorConditionFulfilled() {
  const value = 5;

  console.time('testSpreadOperatorConditionFulfilled');
  for (let i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    let a = {
      ...(value && {b: value})
    };
  }
  console.timeEnd('testSpreadOperatorConditionFulfilled');
}

function testSpreadOperatorConditionNotFulfilled() {
  const value = undefined;

  console.time('testSpreadOperatorConditionNotFulfilled');
  for (let i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    let a = {
      ...(value && {b: value})
    };
  }
  console.timeEnd('testSpreadOperatorConditionNotFulfilled');
}

function testClassicConditionFulfilled() {
  const value = 5;

  console.time('testClassicConditionFulfilled');
  for (let i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    let a = {};
    if (value)
        a.b = value;
  }
  console.timeEnd('testClassicConditionFulfilled');
}

function testClassicConditionNotFulfilled() {
  const value = undefined;

  console.time('testClassicConditionNotFulfilled');
  for (let i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    let a = {};
    if (value)
        a.b = value;
  }
  console.timeEnd('testClassicConditionNotFulfilled');
}

testClassicConditionFulfilled(); // ~ 234.9ms
testClassicConditionNotFulfilled(); // ~493.1ms
testSpreadOperatorConditionFulfilled(); // ~2649.4ms
testSpreadOperatorConditionNotFulfilled(); // ~2278.0ms
```

Comment: practically i don't think it makes diff with small json object

Comment: Classic approach is also super easy so I don't really see the point in getting fancy here.

Comment: The test uses an `N` of 200M. And the slowest still takes less than 3 seconds so its fine to use any depending on your application.

Answer (score 61):

**SIMPLE ES6 SOLUTION**

**Single condition with (&) - `if condition`**

```js
const didIPassExam = true

const study = {
  monday : 'writing',
  tuesday : 'reading',
  
  /* check conditionally and if true, then add wednesday to study */

  ...(didIPassExam && {wednesday : 'sleep happily'})
}


console.log(study)
```

**Dual condition with (? :) - `if-else condition`**

```js
const score = 110
//const score = 10

const storage = {
  a:10,
  b:20,
  ...(score > 100  ? {c: 30} : {d:40}) 
}

console.log(storage)
```

**Explanation**

Let's say you have `storage` object like this

```js
const storage = {
  a : 10,
  b : 20,
}
```

and you would like to add a prop to this conditionally based on `score`

```js
const score = 90
```

You would now like to add prop `c:30` to `storage` if `score` is greater than `100`.

If score is less than `100`, then you want to add  `d:40` to `storage`. You can do like this

```js
const score = 110

const storage = {
  a:10,
  b:20,
  ...(score > 100  ? {c: 30} : {d:40}) 
}
```

The above code gives `storage` as

```js
{
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 30
}
```

If `score = 90`

then you get `storage` as

```js
{
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  d: 40
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sandeepamarnath/pen/gOKrgwg?editors=1111)

Comment: Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to the MDN docs on this syntax (spread syntax)

Comment: What if I want to include "c" when a condition is met and don't do anything when condition is not met.

Comment: @Vasanth, see the first example `const didIPassExam = true` You might be looking for something similar

Comment: Thanks for the response @SandeepAmarnath my problem solved !!

Answer (score 32):

What about using Enhanced Object Properties and only set the property if it is truthy, e.g.:

```
[isConditionTrue() && 'propertyName']: 'propertyValue'
```

So if the condition is not met it doesn't create the preferred property and thus you can discard it.
See: http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames

**UPDATE:**
It is even better to follow the approach of Axel Rauschmayer in his blog article about conditionally adding entries inside object literals and arrays (http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html):

```
const arr = [
  ...(isConditionTrue() ? [{
    key: 'value'
  }] : [])
];

const obj = {
  ...(isConditionTrue() ? {key: 'value'} : {})
};
```

Quite helped me a lot.

Comment: It will almost work. The problem is that it will add an extra `false` key. For instance, 
    
   `{[true && 'a']: 17, [false && 'b']: 42}` is `{a:17, false: 42}`

Comment: I found a more concise way:

`...isConditionTrue() && { propertyName: 'propertyValue' }`

Comment: Better way: ...(isConditionTrue() ? {key: 'value'} : {})

Comment: The Axel Rauschmayer blog link makes this answer.  The "...insertIf(cond, 'a')" example in the article is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 14):

This is probably the shortest solution with ES6

```js
console.log({
   ...true && {foo: 'bar'}
})
// Output: {foo:'bar'}
```

```js
console.log({
   ...false && {foo: 'bar'}
})
// Output: {}
```

Comment: what if we want to spread all the keys of the object into an existing object ? Not just "foo"

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Add another spread.

Comment: Like  ...false &&  ...{}

Answer (score 14):

I made a [small benchmark](https://github.com/icetbr/experiments/blob/main/perf/test/conditionallyAddPropertyToObject.js) with one other option. I like to remove "dead weight" from some objects. Usually falsy values.

Here are the `benny` results:

### clean

```js
const clean = o => {
    for (const prop in o) if (!o) delete o[prop];
}

clean({ value });
```

### spread

```js
let a = {
    ...(value && {b: value})
};
```

### if

```js
let a = {};
if (value) {
    a.b = value;
}
```

### results

```markdown
clean  :  84 918 483 ops/s, ±1.16%    | 51.58% slower    
spread :  20 188 291 ops/s, ±0.92%    | slowest, 88.49% slower    
if     : 175 368 197 ops/s, ±0.50%    | fastest
```

Answer (score 10):

I would do this

```js
var a = someCondition ? { b: 5 } : {};
```

Comment: Much better, thank you. Now the only problem is duplication if there are mandatory arguments (`var o = cond ? {a: 1} : {a: 1, b: 2}`).

Answer (score 7):

If the goal is to have the object appear self-contained and be within one set of braces, you could try this:

```
var a = new function () {
    if (conditionB)
        this.b = 5;

    if (conditionC)
        this.c = 5;

    if (conditionD)
        this.d = 5;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add all your undefined values with no condition and then use `JSON.stringify` to remove them all :

```
const person = {
  name: undefined,
  age: 22,
  height: null
}

const cleaned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));

// Contents of cleaned:

// cleaned = {
//   age: 22,
//   height: null
// }
```

Comment: This is considered quite slow which might be a factor for big objects but more importantly, it will not only remove undefined values but also any functions defined in your object.

Answer (score 5):

This has long been answered, but looking at other ideas I came up with some interesting derivative:

### Assign undefined values to the same property and delete it afterwards

Create your object using an anonymous constructor and always assign undefined members to the same *dummy* member which you remove at the very end. This will give you a single line (not too complex I hope) per member + 1 additional line at the end.

```
var a = new function() {
    this.AlwaysPresent = 1;
    this[conditionA ? "a" : "undef"] = valueA;
    this[conditionB ? "b" : "undef"] = valueB;
    this[conditionC ? "c" : "undef"] = valueC;
    this[conditionD ? "d" : "undef"] = valueD;
    ...
    delete this.undef;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to do this server side (without jquery), you can use lodash 4.3.0:

```
a = _.pickBy({ b: (someCondition? 5 : undefined) }, _.negate(_.isUndefined));
```

---

And this works using lodash 3.10.1

```
a = _.pick({ b: (someCondition? 5 : undefined) }, _.negate(_.isUndefined));
```

Comment: No need for lodash in ES6.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = {
    ...(condition ? {b: 1} : '') // if condition is true 'b' will be added.
}
```

I hope this is the much efficient way to add an entry based on the condition.
For more info on how to conditionally add entries inside an object literals.

Comment: `[...condition?'':['item']]` this will add string item into array

Comment: How is this answer any better than [Jamie Hill's answer from a year earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/40560953#40560953)?

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash library, you can use **_.omitBy**

```
var a = _.omitBy({
    b: conditionB ? 4 : undefined,
    c: conditionC ? 5 : undefined,
}, _.IsUndefined)
```

This results handy when you have requests that are optional

```
var a = _.omitBy({
    b: req.body.optionalA,  //if undefined, will be removed
    c: req.body.optionalB,
}, _.IsUndefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most succinct solution I can come up with:

```
var a = {};
conditionB && a.b = 5;
conditionC && a.c = 5;
conditionD && a.d = 5;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

i prefere, using code this it, you can run this code

```
const three = {
  three: 3
}

// you can active this code, if you use object `three is null`
//const three = {}

const number = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  ...(!!three && three),
  four: 4
}

console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the ES6 based answers, I created this utility Typescript functions, that make the usage (in my opinion) more readable and less like a magical formula, and the intention very clear, and has the correct types:

```
/**
 * Creates a simple object with ot without the specified property and value, depending on the condition.
 * Usage: When creating an object literal that needs to include a property only in some cases.
 * Use it with the spread operator.
 * @example
 * const user = {
 *   username,
 *   // will include the property only if isInternalUser() returns true
 *   ...conditionalObjectProperty('password', isInternalUser(), () => getUserPassword())
 * }
 * @param propertyName
 * @param condition
 * @param valueCreator
 */
export function conditionalObjectProperty<P extends string, V> (propertyName: P, condition: boolean, valueCreator: () => V) {
  return condition
    ? { [propertyName]: valueCreator() }
    : {};
}

/**
 * Specialized conditional property creator that creates an object containing a specified property
 * only when its value is non-nullable.
 * Use in object literals with the spread operator.
 * @example
 * const middleName: string|undefined = getMiddleName();
 * const user = {
 *   userName,
 *   firstName,
 *   lastName,
 *   // will be included only if middleName is non-nullable
 *   ...optionalObjectProperty('middleName', middleName)
 * }
 * @param propertyName
 * @param value
 */
export function optionalObjectProperty<P extends string, V> (propertyName: P, value: V) {
  return conditionalObjectProperty(propertyName, value != null, () => value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first approach to adding members conditionally is perfectly fine. I don't really agree with not wanting to have a member `b` of `a` with a value of `undefined`. It's simple enough to add an `undefined` check with usage of a `for` loop with the `in` operator. But anyways, you could easily write a function to filter out `undefined` members.

```
var filterUndefined = function(obj) {
  var ret = {};
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && value !== undefined) {
      ret[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return ret;
};

var a = filterUndefined({
  b: (conditionB? 5 : undefined),
  c: (conditionC? 5 : undefined),
  d: (conditionD? 5 : undefined),
  e: (conditionE? 5 : undefined),
  f: (conditionF? 5 : undefined),
  g: (conditionG? 5 : undefined),
});
```

You could also use the `delete` operator to edit the object in place.

Answer (score -1):

Using lodash library, you can use **_.merge**

```
var a = _.merge({}, {
    b: conditionB ? 4 : undefined,
    c: conditionC ? 5 : undefined,
})
```

1. If conditionB is `false` & conditionC is `true`, then `a = { c: 5 }`
2. If both conditionB & conditionC are `true`, then `a = { b: 4, c: 5 }`
3. If both conditionB & conditionC are `false`, then `a = {}`

Comment: I get a different result. I'm using `lodash@^4.0.0`. `undefined` are being included in my case.

Comment: @JohnnyQ As of [Lodash version 4.17.21](https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/), `_.merge({}, { x: undefined, y: 1 });` returns `{ "y": 1 }`.

Answer (score -1):

**Wrap into an object**

Something like this is a bit cleaner

```
 const obj = {
   X: 'dataX',
   Y: 'dataY',
   //...
 }

 const list = {
   A: true && 'dataA',
   B: false && 'dataB',
   C: 'A' != 'B' && 'dataC',
   D: 2000 < 100 && 'dataD',
   // E: conditionE && 'dataE',
   // F: conditionF && 'dataF',
   //...
 }

 Object.keys(list).map(prop => list[prop] ? obj[prop] = list[prop] : null)
```

**Wrap into an array**

Or if you want to use Jamie Hill's method and have a very long list of conditions then you must write `...` syntax multiple times. To make it a bit cleaner, you can just wrap them into an array, then use `reduce()` to return them as a single object.

```
const obj = {
  X: 'dataX',
  Y: 'dataY',
  //...

...[
  true && { A: 'dataA'},
  false && { B: 'dataB'},
  'A' != 'B' && { C: 'dataC'},
  2000 < 100 && { D: 'dataD'},
  // conditionE && { E: 'dataE'},
  // conditionF && { F: 'dataF'},
  //...

 ].reduce(( v1, v2 ) => ({ ...v1, ...v2 }))
}
```

Or using `map()` function

```
const obj = {
  X: 'dataX',
  Y: 'dataY',
  //...
}

const array = [
  true && { A: 'dataA'},
  false &&  { B: 'dataB'},
  'A' != 'B' && { C: 'dataC'},
  2000 < 100 && { D: 'dataD'},
  // conditionE && { E: 'dataE'},
  // conditionF && { F: 'dataF'},
  //...

 ].map(val => Object.assign(obj, val))
```

Answer (score -2):

For the sake of completeness you can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) if you want to add additional [descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description). Note I purposely added `enumerable: true` otherwise the property wouldn't appear in the `console.log()`. The advantage with this approach is that you can also use [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) if you want to add **multiple new properties** (However, in this way every property will be dependent on the same condition...)

```js
const select = document.getElementById("condition");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
let a = {};
let b = {};

select.onchange = (e) => {
  const condition = e.target.value === "true";
  condition
    ? Object.defineProperty(a, "b", {
        value: 5,
        enumerable: true,
      })
    : (a = {});

  condition
    ? Object.defineProperties(b, {
        c: {
          value: 5,
          enumerable: true,
        },
        d: {
          value: 6,
          enumerable: true,
        },
        e: {
          value: 7,
          enumerable: true,
        },
      })
    : (b = {});

  outputSingle.innerText = JSON.stringify(a);
  outputMultiple.innerText = JSON.stringify(b);
};
```

```html
Condition:
<select id="condition">
  <option value="false">false</option>
  <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
Single Property: <pre id="outputSingle">{}</pre><br/>
Multiple Properties: <pre id="outputMultiple">{}</pre>
```

Answer (score -3):

Define a var by `let` and just assign new property

```js
let msg = {
    to: "hito@email.com",
    from: "hifrom@email.com",
    subject: "Contact form",    
};

if (file_uploaded_in_form) { // the condition goes here
    msg.attachments = [ // here 'attachments' is the new property added to msg Javascript object
      {
        content: "attachment",
        filename: "filename",
        type: "mime_type",
        disposition: "attachment",
      },
    ];
}
```

Now the `msg` become

```
{
    to: "hito@email.com",
    from: "hifrom@email.com",
    subject: "Contact form",
    attachments: [
      {
        content: "attachment",
        filename: "filename",
        type: "mime_type",
        disposition: "attachment",
      },
    ]
}
```

In my opinion this is very simple and easy solution.

Comment: you can add new properties to objects even when they are `const`