# Conditionally set an object property

Tags: javascript

Is there some syntax for setting properties based on a condition?

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36,
    express: (myCondition ? true : null) // does not work
}
```

I want `express` to be either set to a value or not set at all (i.e., there should be no key named `express`), and without extra statements after the definition. I know I can use it as a boolean, but the receiving side is using an `isset()` check and I'm wondering if I can avoid modifying it.

---

**Edit**: Seems there is no direct solution to the problem as stated. Here are the close suggestions:

**JSON.stringify** (Chris Kessel, dystroy):

```
var json = JSON.stringify( {
    data: {
        userId: 7,
        actionId: 36,
        express: (myCondition ? true : null)
    }
});
```

**An anonymous function** (Paulpro):

```
var data = new function(){
    this.userId = 7;
    this.actionId = 36;
    myCondition && (this.express = true);
};
```

**An extra statement** (x4rf41):

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36
}
if(myCondition) data["express"] = true;
```

**Eval** (a former colleague of mine):

```
eval("data = {userId: 7, actionId: 36 " + (myCondition ? ", express: true}" : "}"))
```

**Conditional definition** (don't really know how to label this one):

```
data = (
    (myCondition && { userId: 7, actionId: 36, express: true }) ||
    (!myCondition && { userId: 7, actionId: 36 })
);
```

Comment: when you say "not set at all", do you mean the property exists but has the value `undefined`, or the property does not exist?

Comment: I mean the property should not exist at all.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi I think you meant object properties, not JSON properties. There is no JSON in your question.

Comment: @Paulpro: I think you are right :)

Comment: A lot of interesting answers, so determining whose to select was tough. Thanks for the input, all of you.

Comment: loved different alternate options listed within the question

Comment: Duplicate of [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36,
    express: (myCondition ? true : undefined)
}
```

A property whose value is `undefined` isn't written when you [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the object to JSON.

---

EDIT : It appears from the comments that there is no JSON involved in fact. OP is using `$.ajax` so `$.param` is probably used. `$.param`, unfortunately, does create an entry for properties whose value is `undefined`. So there's probably no solution without any supplementary line of code.

Comment: I'm just supplying it to an AJAX call and it's not stripped away - I'm not explicitly stringifying it ATM.

Comment: I don't know your API but it's almost sure it's calling JSON.stringify. Even if it doesn't, the norm doesn't allow to pass undefined value, so any API **must** remove properties whose value is `undefined`.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, and I don't know what it does with the object, but the property remains there.

Comment: jquery ajax wont stringify, i guess you just have to write an extra line. thats gotta be horrible

Comment: It's not a problem. I'm just wondering if it is possible without the extra step.

Comment: +1 for JSON.stringify ignoring undefined properties. learned something new, thanks

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi Is JSON involved somewhere as you wrote or are you (implicitely) calling $.param ?

Comment: @dystroy: Not sure - I think I'm (jQuery is) implicitly calling `$.param` . I just thought the question depends on JSON syntax enough to label it as such.

Comment: If you don't produce JSON, there there's no relation with JSON.

Comment: This won't work and will have a property with undefined.

Comment: @sean yes, a property does exist, but I was running the object through `JSON.stringify` after construction.

Answer (score 120):

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals).

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36,
    ...myCondition && {express: true}
}
```

Note that if you're using [Flow](https://flow.org/), that syntax might generate type check errors. You can write the above more explicitly, and less succinctly, as:-

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36,
    ...(myCondition ? {express: true} : {})
}
```

Comment: if don't want empty object: ...(myCondition ? {express: true} : null)
then filter null by: data = data.filter(function(x) { return x !== null });

Comment: @user1345817 Just to chime in, the update you added is not needed because the spread in the answer (`...`) eliminates the empty object (`{}`) in the falsy case of the ternary. Thus, the property is only added in the truthy case.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it if you define your object using an anonymous function instead of object literal notation:

```
var data = new function(){
    this.userId = 7;
    this.actionId = 36;
    myCondition && (this.express = true);
};
```

The resulting `data` object is the exact same, except it's `constructor` will be the anonymous function instead of `window.Object`.

Answer (score 5):

first of all, thats javascript, not JSON.

the solution:

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36
}
if(myCondition) data["express"] = true;
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer : *"without extra statemets after the definition"*. Obviously OP knew he could do that.

Comment: This won't work in ES6. showing me prettier and linting errors

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify( {
    data: {
        userId: 7,
        actionId: 36,
        express: (myCondition ? true : null)
    }
});
```

Comment: `null` is not stripped, `undefined` is.

Comment: Yep, very true. I was just echoing in my code what was in the original.

Answer (score 3):

The spread operator now fixes this. Here is an example with two comparisons.

Note: I changed `date:` to `const date =`  so that it is valid runnable javascript. This can also be used with `data:` if it is supposed to be inside of a deep object structure.

```js
const compareValue = 13;
const data =  {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36,
    ...(compareValue > 10 && {propertyForGreaterThan10: 'foo'}),
    ...(compareValue < 10 && {propertyForLessThan10: 'bar'}),
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit old but there is a good solution as well you can do :

```
data: {
    userId: 7,
    actionId: 36
}

Object.assign(data, !myCondition && { express: yourValue });
```

Thus it will assign your express property with the value you need if your condition is false.