# How to conditionally add properties to a javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to do the following to satisfy the requirements of a code builder (Sencha Cmd to be specific).

This is the essence I what I need to do. The critical factor is that the function body MUST end with a return of an object literal. I cant return a variable due to restrictions in the builder. So, how to add a property 'b' at the point of the pseudo code below if the parameter 'includeB' is true, but NOT add a property AT ALL if it is false. ie b==undefined or b==null is not allowed.

Perhaps it is not possible.

```
function create(includeB) {
        // Can have code here but the final thing MUST be a return of the literal.
        // ...
    return {
        a : 1
        // pseudo code:
        // if (includeB==true) then create a property called b 
        // and assign a value of 2 to it. 
        // Must be done right here within this object literal
    }
}

var obj = create(false);
// obj must have property 'a' ONLY

var obj = create(true);
// obj must have properties 'a' and 'b'
```

Thanks for reading and considering,

Murray

Comment: what prevents you from changing the object returned by the function? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't have access to it. The builder is reading the JS from the file system using a Java app (Sencha Cmd). The function provided is a test case since trying to demonstrate the complete real situation would have been too confusing. The test case was the essence of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally set a JSON object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019854/conditionally-set-a-json-object-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've pretty much shown a use case for a constructor function instead of using an object literal:

```
function CustomObject(includeB) {
    this.a = 1;
    if (includeB) {
        this.b = 2;
    }
}

//has `a` only
var obj1 = new CustomObject(false);

//has `a` and `b`
var obj2 = new CustomObject(true);
```

---

After re-reading your question it appears that you've got limited access in modifying the function. If I'm understanding your question correctly you can only change a limited portion of the script:

```
function create(includeB) {
    // modifications may be done here

    // the rest may not change
    return {
        a : 1
    }
}

var obj = create(false);
// obj must have property 'a' ONLY

var obj = create(true);
// obj must have properties 'a' and 'b'
```

If that's the case, then you could simply skip the later part of the function:

```
function create(includeB) {
    if (includeB) {
        return {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        };
    }
    return {
        a: 1
    };
}
```

Comment: OK. Sorry for the delay. I was testing this solution in the real app with the builder. Yes! This syntax is acceptable to the builder. I had previously tried by using an 'else' block but didn't think to try just a plain return. Thank you!

Comment: To be clear, this is the syntax that kept the builder happy:
 
    function create(includeB) {
        if (includeB) {
            return {
                a: 1,
                b: 2
            };
        }
        return {
            a: 1
        };
    }

Answer (score 58):

If you can use ES6, use the [spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

```
function create(includeB) {
    return {
        a : 1,
        ...(includeB ? { b: 2 } : {}),
    };
}
```

Comment: This is elegant syntax in many cases, but requires Object Rest/Spread, which currently is currently (2017-10-29) only a Stage 3 proposal for some future ECMAScript version; work well with Babel's transform, though.

Comment: you can even write `...(includeB && { b: 2 } )`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put boolean logic inside a javascript literal definition.  So, if your builder requires the the returned object can ONLY be defined as a javascript literal, then you cannot define properties conditionally that way.

---

If you can create an object inside your function, modify that object using logic and then return that object, then that's pretty easy.

```
function create(includeB) {
    var x = {
        a: 1
    };
    if (includeB) {
        x.b = 2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

---

Your other option would be to wrap the create function and do it outside the create function.

```
function myCreate(includeB) {
    var x = create(includeB)
    if (includeB) {
        x.b = 2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

---

Or, you could even wrap the create function transparently so callers still use `create()`, but it's behavior has been altered.

```
var oldCreate = create;
create = function(includeB) {
    var x = oldCreate(includeB);
    if (includeB) {
        x.b = 2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it must be done within the literal. I thought I was probably asking a lot!

Comment: @Murrah - I added two more option that have you wrap the create function and add your logic outside the existing `create()` function.

Comment: Thanks. Again, the builder requirement in the specific situation is that whatever function I give it, it must have the literal return. return x; is "illegal" in the specific case.

Comment: @Murrah - My last two suggestions did not modify the actual `create()` function.  It can be left as is without the `.b` property.  I was suggesting how you could add some plain javascript that would wrap or modify the `create()` function to make it behave the way you wanted.  Can you not add regular javascript to your project?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this, and found you could use a self-calling function within an object's definition (if using ES6).  This is similar to the accepted answer, but might be useful for others who need to do this without first defining a constructor function.

For example:

```
let obj = (() => {
  let props = { a: 1 };
  if ( 1 ) props.b = 2;
  return props;
})();
```

makes the object: { a: 1, b: 2 }

It's handy for more complicated objects, keeping the construction continuous:

```
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: (() => {
    let props = { b1: 1 };
    if ( 1 ) props.b2 = 2;
    return props;
    })(),
  c: 3
}
```

makes the object:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: {
    b1: 1,
    b2: 2
  },
  c: 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define it later:

```
var hasA = create(); // has hasA.a

var hasBoth = create();
hasBoth.b = 2; //now has both
```

Alternatively, using your argument in `create`:

```
function create (includeB) {
  var obj = { 
    a : 1
  };
  if (includeB) {
     obj.b = 2;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Yes, normally that is what I would do. As I say, in this case due to external requirements, I cannot do that because the code builder is essentially consuming the result of the create function, so I dont have access to it. If it is possible at all it MUST be done where the pseudo code is.

Comment: @Murrah You wouldn't be able to do it within an object.  Perhaps you could try option #1 in my answer?

Comment: @Murrah: An object literal has a very specific syntax. This syntax doesn't provide any means to conditionally set a property.

Comment: You could set b to be a function which returns 2 or undefined @Murrah

Comment: Correct @zzzzBov, but it's an option.  Honestly, the example given in the question doesn't seem sufficient for whatever real problem OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function create(includeB) {
    return includeB && { a:1, b:2 } || { a:1 };
}
```

When `includeB` is true, the create function will return `{a:1, b:2}`. If `includeB` is false, it will return whatever is after the `or` - in this case, the `{a:1}` object.

`create(true)` returns `{ a:1, b:2 }`.

`create(false)` returns `{ a:1 }`

Comment: I think you're looking for ternary notation: condition ? true : false;

Comment: I'm not sure what this notation is called, but it seems to do what the OP asked for.

Comment: I guess it's another ternary.  I expected it to return boolean or an object.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work. I hope this help.

function create(includeB){

```
var object = {
    a: 1
};

if (includeB)
    object.b = 2;

return object;
```

}

Comment: Thanks. Same as above, cant return an object, must be a literal.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a declaration to satisfy the same requirement once without too much bloat, you can also simply do the following:

```
var created = function(includeB) {
    var returnObj = { a : 1 };

    if(includeB) { returnObj.b = 2; }

    return returnObj;
}}(); //automatically runs and assigns returnObj to created
```