# How to make header object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, axios

If I make the `headers` and would change conditionally:

```js
let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
}
if (authnRes?.data?.jwt) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authnRes?.data?.jwt}`
}
```

I will get an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"Authorization"' can't be used to index type '{ 'Content-Type': string; crossDomain: boolean; }'.
  Property 'Authorization' does not exist on type '{ 'Content-Type': string; crossDomain: boolean; }'.
```

How can I solve it? Is it maybe a predefined `axios` type for Headers?

```
axios({
    // ..
    headers: headers,
})
    .then((resp: any) => {
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

--

Is it any easier way then this below?

```
let headers: {
    [key: string]: string | boolean
} = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally add properties to a javascript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568760/how-to-conditionally-add-properties-to-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: I think it is too complex what you shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `AxiosRequestHeaders` from `axios` and use it to type your `headers` variable, like so :

```
import { AxiosRequestHeaders } from 'axios';
let headers: AxiosRequestHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  crossDomain: true,
};
```

By the way, if you go and look at the type definition you'll see it's very similar to your attempt:

```
type AxiosRequestHeaders = {
  [x: string]: string | number | boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still got an error with @coglialoro solution, solved it by using this notation:

```
import type { AxiosRequestHeaders } from 'axios';
let headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  crossDomain: true,
} as AxiosRequestHeaders;
```