# jQuery : How to ignore an element to the JSON Array if it is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to ignore the fields to the json array if a particular field is null or blank. I am doing the null validation insdie the json object which is currently throws error. Kindly advice how do i ignore a null field to the json object.

```
var requestType = $("#requestType").val();
var requestorName = $("#requestorName").val();
var requestorDept =$("#requestorDept").val();
var requestorLocation =$("#requestorLocation").val();

var data = {
   if(requestType!=undefined && requestType!=null && requestType !='')
    {
       "RequestType" : requestType,
     }

   if(requestorName!=undefined && requestorName!=null && requestorName!='')
    {
        "RequestorName" : requestorName,
    }

  "RequestorDept" : requestorDept,
  "RequestorLocation" : requestorLocation
}
```

I am getting the error as below

```
SyntaxError : missing ) after formal parameters
if(requestType !=undefined && issueType !=null && issueType !='')
```

Comment: *currently throws error*, what is the error?

Comment: @ShaunakD i have updated the error details.

Comment: This **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18020466/3639582)** might help. Usage of `if()..` inside obj literal is not a correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a utility method like below

```
var validateNull=function(value){
        if(value!==undefined || value !== "null" || value !== "undefined" || value !== "" ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

While creating JSON use it like this

```
    var data = {};
if(validateNull(requestType )){
     data.requestType=requestType ; 
}
```

...Similar for all other fields