# Add Object to another object with a condition check

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
import { required, email, numeric } from 'validators'
let fields = ['name', 'email'];
validations: {
  name: {
     required
  },
  email: {
     required,
     email
  }
}
```

Now, I wanna do the require condition for each validation objects with a condition check.

Something like:

```
(fields.indexOf('name') > -1) ? 'required' : '';
```

How can I do this to dynamically set the validation conditions?

```
validations: {
  name: {
     (fields.indexOf('name') > -1) ? 'required' : '';
  },
  email: {
     (fields.indexOf('email') > -1) ? 'required' : '';,
     (fields.indexOf('email') > -1) ? 'email' : '';
  }
}
```

P.S: I know the above syntax is wrong. But wanted to achieve something like this.

Comment: `{required: (fields.indexOf('name') > -1) ? required : false}` ? If you want to conditionally add the property, then you have to do this after the object is created: `if (fields.indexOf('name') > -1) { validations.name.required = required; }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704267/218196)