# In Javascript, how to conditionally update a property of an object?

Tags: javascript

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object) and was wondering if there was a way of using javascript to write a function that could conditionally update all properties of an object by using another object with the new values?

Say I have this object:

```
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
```

And I want to update its values using the properties passed by another object like this:

```
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2'}
```

In this case I just want to update property "test2". If I know the properties I want to update and I know the original properties beforehand, I'll use:

```
oldObj = {
  ...(newObj.test1) && {test1: newObj.test1} || {test1: oldObj.test1},
  ...(newObj.test2) && {test2: newObj.test2} || {test2: oldObj.test2},
  ...(newObj.test3) && {test3: newObj.test3} || {test3: oldObj.test3},
};
```

Meaning I will only update the value if the property comes in the new object, but of course I would have to add as many conditions as there are properties in the object.

This approach is fine, but it's not generalised so if the object has 10 properties, I would have to write 10 conditions.

Is there a way of writing a function that could conditionally update the properties so that I don't have to write the 10 (or more) conditions?

Comment: How about looping over all the properties in the json and checking for matches from the `newJson´??

Comment: There is no JSON in your question, I suggest different variable names. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I think you are looking for objects merging (Not sure), take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Since your title is asking about *updating* a property, not creating one in a new object, why not just use `Object.assign`?

Comment: You *definitely* should have simplified and corrected that to `jsonObj = {
  test1: newJson.test1 ? newJson.test1: jsonObj.test1,
  test2: newJson.test2 ? newJson.test2 : jsonObj.test2,
  test3: newJson.test3 ? newJson.test3: jsonObj.test3,
};` Don't use object literals inside spread syntax, and don't use short-circuiting `||` and `&&` instead of the conditional operator!

Comment: Clarify something: if `newJson` had a property called "xyz", do you want to ignore that (because there's no "xyz" property in `jsonObj`), or do you want the set of all properties from both source objects in the result?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, changed the question.

Comment: @Exception_al I've thought of that, but was looking for an alternative.

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher exactly what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @Pointy I will only update properties that exist in the old object, new properties that don't exist in the old object will not be added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> I will only update properties that exist in the old object, new properties that don't exist in the old object will not be added.

That means we have to leave spread syntax and `Object.assign` out of the picture, as both of them would copy **all** properties from `newObj` over to `oldObj`.

Instead, we can use a simple loop (and if this comes up a lot, you can create a function, perhaps `updateObject`):

```
for (const key of Object.keys(newObj)) {
  if (key in oldObj) {
    oldObj[key] = newObj[key];
  }
}
```

```js
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2', xyz: "don't copy me"};

for (const key of Object.keys(newObj)) {
  if (key in oldObj) {
    oldObj[key] = newObj[key];
  }
}
console.log(oldObj);
```

(You may prefer `oldObj.hasOwnProperty(key)` instead of `key in oldObj`, depending on your rules for updating.)

Or using the relatively-new `Object.entries` and some destructuring:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newObj)) {
  if (key in oldObj) {
    oldObj[key] = value;
  }
}
```

```js
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2', xyz: "don't copy me"};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(newObj)) {
  if (key in oldObj) {
    oldObj[key] = value;
  }
}
console.log(oldObj);
```

---

Before the clarification quoted above, I'd posted the following about spread and `Object.assign`. Just for completeness, but they don't apply to your case where you want to skip properties that `oldObj` doesn't have:

You don't have to be anything like that complicated with the spread syntax, just:

```
oldObj = {...oldObj, ...newObj};
```

```js
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2', xyz: "I get copied too"};

oldObj = {...oldObj, ...newObj};
console.log(oldObj);
```

That will create a new object with all of `oldObj`'s and `newObj`'s properties, with `newObj`'s properties winning if both have the same name.

Note that property spread is *brand-new*, just approved to Stage 4 (will be in the ES2018 spec). If you don't want to use a Stage 4 proposal, use `Object.assign`:

```
oldObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj, newObj);
```

```js
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2', xyz: "I get copied too"};

oldObj = Object.assign({}, oldObj, newObj);
console.log(oldObj);
```

You'd also use `Object.assign` if you want to update `oldObj` in-place instead of creating a new object:

```
Object.assign(oldObj, newObj);
```

```js
let oldObj = {test1: 'valueTest1',test2: 'valueTest2',test3: 'valueTest3' };
let newObj = {test2: 'newValue2', xyz: "I get copied too"};

Object.assign(oldObj, newObj);
console.log(oldObj);
```

---

Comment: The only thing is that this will pick up *all* properties from `newJson`, but my reading of the OP suggests that maybe that's not what's desired.

Comment: Well for example it's not clear what should happen if `newJson` has a property called "xyz". Should that be in the result object or not?

Comment: @Pointy: That *seems* to be the goal (weird not to show unrelated properties in the example otherwise). I just went and posted a comment asking -- then deleted it when yours appeared! :-)

Comment: @Pointy: I've covered my bases now, just in case. :-)

Comment: In my case Object.assign(jsonObj, newJson); did the trick. I had already used the "hasOwnProperty" function and loop, but was looking for an alternative. Keep in mind that If the new object has new properties they will get added using this approach. I'm validating that before so I don't have that problem.

Comment: @c-chavez: Yup. When I saw your comment, I reordered the answer to put the versions that don't do that up top (and to rename the variables).