# Passing props to Material UI styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Given the `Card` code as in [here](https://mui.com/components/cards/#main-content). How can I update the card style or any material UI style as  from:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
  minWidth: 275,
},
```

To such follows:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
  minWidth: 275, backgroundColor: props.color
},
```

when I tried the latest one, I got

```
Line 15:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
```

when I updated code to be :

```
const styles = theme =>  (props) => ({
  card: {
  minWidth: 275, backgroundColor: props.color
},
```

also

```
 const styles  = (theme ,props) => ({
   card: {
   minWidth: 275, backgroundColor: props.color
 },
```

Instead of

```
const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
  minWidth: 275, backgroundColor: props.color
},
```

I got the component card style at the web page messy.

By the way, I pass props as follows:

```
<SimpleCard backgroundColor="#f5f2ff" />
```

please help!

Comment: @pritesh That will be much-unneeded code, while needed code I already showed it. Furthermore, I gave reference to the original card code at material ui website. So shall I display whole code? Remeber I am not talking about a bug, I am asking how to accomplish something. If I talk about a bug, then I have to show what code I have written. But for how to do something, it is enough I showed my tries above using code. What is your opinion now?

Comment: Since you are accessing props inside styles function so if the styles is defined inside react component then only props will be  available for it.`Line 15:  'props' is not defined  no-undef` .You might be getting this error because of it .So it matters where you wrote your style and how you are accessing it.So I am not sure exactly how is your code working.It is better to display the component code only?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would appreciate you if see the code https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/ for styles. Or at sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/ym1q925xj1

Comment: Props aren't available in to `withStyles`.

Comment: thanks @Matt. but how can I achieve my purpose? I am going to include the card inside a map iterator, and many cards will be generated, I want to make them unique by sending different colors to them.

Comment: This may help: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This answer was written prior to version 4.0 severely out of date!**

Seriously, if you're styling a function component, use `makeStyles`.

The [answer from James Tan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036613/571724) is the best answer for version 4.x

**Anything below here is ancient:**

When you're using `withStyles`, you have access to the `theme`, but not `props`.

Please note that there is an [open issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7633) on Github requesting this feature and some of the comments may point you to an alternative solution that may interest you.

One way to change the background color of a card using props would be to set this property using inline styles.  I've forked your [original codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym1q925xj1) with a few changes, you can view the [modified version](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zlw6qmmzx) to see this in action.

Here's what I did:

1. Render the component with a `backgroundColor` prop:

```js
// in index.js
if (rootElement) {
  render(<Demo backgroundColor="#f00" />, rootElement);
}
```

2. Use this prop to apply an inline style to the card:

```js
    function SimpleCard(props) {
      // in demo.js
      const { classes, backgroundColor } = props;
      const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;
      return (
        <div>
          <Card className={classes.card} style={{ backgroundColor }}>
            <CardContent>
              // etc
```

Now the rendered [Card component](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/) has a red (#F00) background

Take a look at the [Overrides](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/) section of the documentation for other options.

Comment: @HugoGresse thanks!  I've touched up your edit a bit, pointing people to the better answer.

Comment: Please consider changing to one of the other answers. Inline styles should be only used as last resort

Comment: @Phil That is my recommendation as well.  A while back, I updated the answer to direct viewers to the one posted by James Tan.

Answer (score 163):

Deleted the old answer, because it's no reason for existence.

Here's what you want:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    firstStyle: {
        backgroundColor: props => props.backgroundColor,
    },
    secondStyle: {
        color: props => props.color,
    },
});

const MyComponent = ({children, ...props}) =>{
    const { firstStyle, secondStyle } = useStyles(props);
    return(
        <div className={`${firstStyle} ${secondStyle}`}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Now you can use it like:

```
<MyComponent color="yellow" backgroundColor="purple">
    Well done
</MyComponent>
```

[Official Documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props)

Comment: Could the same effect (not creating new styled component on each render) be achieved using functional components and hooks? I'm new to React hooks so just asking

Comment: Yes, you can. You may use useEffect hook and pass just style props to it to ensure it will only rerender when style props are changed.

Comment: Could you post an answer with the useEffect hook? I'm using your solution now but want to be as performant as possible and I'm still really new to hooks and not sure how.

Comment: This answer not only helped me to solve this issue in passing props to these style, but also helped me out to understand better about  makeStyles method. Thanks!

Comment: What if I have the `useStyle` declared in a separated file?

I have tried with `const styles = (props) => makeStyles({});` but without luck

Comment: Why is it undefined sometimes

Comment: makeStyles is now deprecated

Answer (score 70):

Solution for how to use both props and theme in material ui :

```
const useStyles = props => makeStyles( theme => ({
    div: {
        width: theme.spacing(props.units || 0)  
    }
}));

export default function ComponentExample({ children, ...props }){
    const { div } = useStyles(props)();
    return (
        <div className={div}>{children}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This is money for *`props`* and *`theme`*

Comment: If `useStyles` is in a separate file this doesn't seem to work. Any solution for it?

Comment: @SrinjoySantra are you sure you added another () after your style declaration?
const { div } = useStyles(props)();

Answer (score 62):

Here the **Typescript** solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {Theme} from '@material-ui/core';

export interface StyleProps {
    height: number;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>(theme => ({
  root: {
    background: 'green',
    height: ({height}) => height,
  },
}));

export default function Hook() {

  const props = {
    height: 48
  }

  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Styled with Hook API</Button>;
}
```

If you want to play with it, try it in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styles-with-props-6jp0c?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 57):

In **MUI v5**, this is how you access the props when creating the style object using [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content):

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme, myColor }) => ({
  backgroundColor: myColor,
  width: 30,
  height: 30
}));
```

For folks who use typescript, you also need to add the prop type to the `CreateStyledComponent`:

```
type DivProps = {
  myColor: string;
};

const Div = styled(Box)<DivProps>(({ theme, myColor }) => ({
  backgroundColor: myColor,
  width: 30,
  height: 30
}));
```

```
<StyledBox myColor="pink" />
```

If you want to use [system props](https://mui.com/system/properties/) in your custom component like `Box` and `Typography`, you can use `extendSxProp` like the example below:

```
import { unstable_extendSxProp as extendSxProp } from "@mui/system";

const StyledDiv = styled("div")({});

function DivWithSystemProps(inProps) {
  const { sx } = extendSxProp(inProps);
  return <StyledDiv sx={sx} />;
}
```

```
<DivWithSystemProps
  bgcolor="green"
  width={30}
  height={30}
  border="solid 1px red"
/>
```

##### Explanation

- **`styled("div")()`**: Add the `sx` props to your custom component
- **`extendSxProp(props)`**: Gather the top level system props and put it inside the `sx` property:

```
const props = { notSystemProps: true, color: 'green', bgcolor: 'red' };
const finalProps = extendSxProp(props);

// finalProps = {
//   notSystemProps: true,
//   sx: { color: 'green', bgcolor: 'red' }
// }
```

To use with typescript, you need to add the type for all system properties:

```
type DivSystemProps = SystemProps<Theme> & {
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
};

function DivWithSystemProps(inProps: DivSystemProps) {
  const { sx, ...other } = extendSxProp(inProps);
  return <StyledDiv sx={sx} {...other} />;
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 38):

[Here's the official Material-UI demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/giubj?file=/demo.js)

And here's a very simple example.  It uses syntax similar to Styled Components:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: props => props.color,
    "&:hover": {
      background: props => props.hover
    }
  },
  label: { fontFamily: props => props.font }
});

export function MyButton(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <Button className={classes.root} classes={{ label: classes.label }}>My Button</Button>;
}


// and the JSX...
<MyButton color="red" hover="blue" font="Comic Sans MS" />
```

This demo uses `makeStyles`, but this feature is also available in [`styled`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-styled-components-api) and [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-higher-order-component-api).

This was first introduced in [@material-ui/styles on Nov 3, 2018](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/13503) and was included in @material-ui/core starting with version 4.

Comment: As I like being able to access props on the property level, in my case it would be better to access it on the styles level `const useStyles = (props) => makeStyles({})`. I get dynamic styles definition from the server and I don't know what CSS properties are defined there. Is it possible with @material-ui/styles?

Comment: @Jagi Since `makeStyles` returns a function that takes `props` and returns `classes`, you could always wrap it within your own custom function that takes `props` and returns `classes`.  For example:`const useStyles = (props) => { /* do stuff */ return makeStyles({}); }`.  Does that solve your problem?  In what ways do you need to change the object passed in to `makeStyles` based on the props coming from the server?

Comment: @Jagi Oops, I meant this: `const useStyles = (props, options) => { /* do stuff */ return makeStyles({})(props, options); }`

Comment: Thanks, it works! The only thing that I'm worried about is that it will recreate styles on each render even when props haven't changed. Or is `makeStyles` taking care of it?

Comment: That's true, `makeStyles` creates a function and that function will be created on every render instead of being created once.  However, two thoughts: 1) if the object that you are passing into `makeStyles` is different on every render, then there's no getting around creating new classes on every render (at least not with Material-UI's current functionality) and 2) I wouldn't worry about performance until you have metrics to show that it's a problem for users.

Comment: Also note that makeStyles is a stateless hook so, it won't work with class components,

Comment: @Dominus.Vobiscum what if i also want to modify the label style as well in that case how can I pass the label style using the className

Comment: @SandeepGahlawat I've updated the answer to show how.

Answer (score 9):

Was missing from this thread a `props` use within `withStyles` (and lead to think it wasn't supported)

But this worked for me (say for styling a `MenuItem`):

```
const StyledMenuItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
 root: {
  '&:focus': {
    backgroundColor: props => props.focusBackground,
    '& .MuiListItemIcon-root, & .MuiListItemText-primary': {
      color: props => props.focusColor,
    },
  },
 },
}))(MenuItem);
```

And then use it as so:

```
 <StyledMenuItem focusColor={'red'} focusBackground={'green'}... >...</StyledMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 9):

@mui v5

You can use [styled() utility](https://mui.com/system/styled/#heading-styled-component-options-styles-component) (Make sure that you're importing the correct one) and `shouldForwardProp` option.
In the following example `SomeProps` passed to a `div` component

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material'

interface SomeProps {
  backgroundColor: 'red'|'blue',
  width: number
}
const CustomDiv  = styled('div', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'someProps' })<{
  someProps: SomeProps;
}>(({ theme, someProps }) => {
  return ({
    backgroundColor: someProps.backgroundColor,
    width: `${someProps.width}em`,
    margin:theme.spacing(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: props => props.color,
    "&:hover": {
      background: props => props.hover
    }
  }
});

export function MyButton(props) {
  const classes = useStyles({color: 'red', hover: 'green'});
  return <Button className={classes.root}>My Button</Button>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution for TypeScript with Class Component:

```
type PropsBeforeStyle = {
  propA: string;
  propB: number;
}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  root: {
    color: (props: PropsBeforeStyle) => {}
  }
});

type Props = PropsBeforeStyle & WithStyles<typeof styles>;

class MyClassComponent extends Component<Props> {...}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyClassComponent);
```

Answer (score 4):

I spent a couple of hours trying to get withStyles to work with passing properties in Typescript. None of the solutions I found online worked with what I was trying to do, so I ended up knitting my own solution together, with snippets from here and there.

This should work if you have external components from, lets say Material UI, that you want to give a default style, but you also want to reuse it by passing different styling options to the component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Theme, createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TableCell, TableCellProps } from '@material-ui/core';

type Props = {
    backgroundColor?: string
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>(theme =>
    createStyles({
        head: {
            backgroundColor: ({ backgroundColor }) => backgroundColor || theme.palette.common.black,
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
            fontSize: 13
        },
        body: {
            fontSize: 12,
        },
    })
);

export function StyledTableCell(props: Props & Omit<TableCellProps, keyof Props>) {
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return <TableCell classes={classes} {...props} />;
}
```

It may not be the perfect solution, but it seems to work. It's a real bugger that they haven't just amended withStyles to accept properties. It would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

```js
export const renderButton = (tag, method, color) => {
  const OkButton = withStyles({
    root: {
      "color": `${color}`,
      "filter": "opacity(0.5)",
      "textShadow": "0 0 3px #24fda39a",
      "backgroundColor": "none",
      "borderRadius": "2px solid #24fda3c9",
      "outline": "none",
      "border": "2px solid #24fda3c9",
      "&:hover": {
        color: "#24fda3c9",
        border: "2px solid #24fda3c9",
        filter: "opacity(1)",
      },
      "&:active": {
        outline: "none",
      },
      "&:focus": {
        outline: "none",
      },
    },
  })(Button);
  return (
    <OkButton tag={tag} color={color} fullWidth onClick={method}>
      {tag}
    </OkButton>
  );
};

renderButton('Submit', toggleAlert, 'red')
```

Comment: I ran into recursive rendering problems with this approach, and had to wrap the withStyles in a useMemo

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of dynamically passing props to hook's API in MUI v5

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { Theme } from "@mui/material";

interface StyleProps {
  height: number;
  backgroundColor: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme>((theme) => ({
  root: ({ height, backgroundColor }: StyleProps) => ({
    background: backgroundColor,
    height: height
  })
}));

export default function Hook() {
  const props = {
    height: 58,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  };

  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <button className={classes.root}>
      another way of passing props to useStyle hooks
    </button>
  );
}
```

here's the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/styles-with-props-forked-gx3bf?file=/demo.tsx:0-607

Answer (score 2):

Here's 2 full working examples of how to pass props to MUI v5 styles. Either using css or javascript object syntax.

With css syntax:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system'

interface Props {
  myColor: string
}

const MyComponent = ({ myColor }: Props) => {
  const MyStyledComponent = styled('div')`
    background-color: ${myColor};

    .my-paragraph {
      color: white;
    }
  `
  return (
    <MyStyledComponent >
      <p className="my-paragraph">Hello there</p>
    </MyStyledComponent >
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Note that we define `MyStyledComponent` within `MyComponent`, making the scoped props available to use in the template string of the `styled()` function.

Same thing with javascript object syntax:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system'

const MyComponent = ({ className }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <p className="my-paragraph">Hello there</p>
    </div>
  )
}

interface Props {
    myColor: string
  }

const MyStyledComponent = styled(MyComponent)((props: Props) => ({
  backgroundColor: props.myColor,
  '.my-paragraph': { color: 'white' },
}))

export default MyStyledComponent
```

For this second example, please note how we pass the `className` to the component we want to apply the styles to. The `styled()` function will pass a `className` prop with the styles you define. You typically want to apply that to your root element. In this case the `div`.

Result:

[image: red square with white text]

I'm sure there's other variations of how to do this, but these two are easy to implement and understand.

You might need to memoize the calculated styles, and maybe not use this approach if your props changes a lot. I don't think it's very performant.

Answer (score 0):

Using `styled-components`, sometimes you only want to apply styles if the prop is passed, in such cases you can do something like this (remove `: {foo: boolean}` if not using TypeScript):

```js
const SAnchor = styled("a", {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== "foo",
})(({foo = false}: {foo: boolean}) => ({
  ...(foo && {
    color: "inherit",
    textDecoration: "none",
  }),
}));
```

[Object spread source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560953/827129)

[`shouldForwardProp` docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop)

Answer (score 0):

@mui v5

I use theme and prop from JSON object

```
const Answerdiv = styled((props) => {
const { item_style, ...other } = props;
return <div  {...other}></div>;
})(({ theme, item_style }) => {
    for(var i of Object.keys(item_style)){
        item_style[i] =Object.byString(theme,item_style[i])|| item_style[i];
}
    return (item_style)
});
```

component use

```
<Answerdiv item_style={(item_style ? JSON.parse(item_style) : {})}>
```

for Object.byString

```
Object.byString = function(o, s) {
        s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
        s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
        var a = s.split('.');
        for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
            var k = a[i];
            if (k in o) {
                o = o[k];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```