# Apply MUI styles to non-MUI markup elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my Gatsby app I am using MUI v5, and must also output user created markup. I want the user-markup to get the same base-styles as their analogous `Typography` elements (see below). How can I achieve this?

Note - the user markup already contains `<p>` `<h1>` or other tags, which cannot be directly modified by React.

Additionally the app is wrapped with `ThemeProvider` and I'm using `styled-components` as the style engine for MUI (if that matters...).

```
import {Typography} from "@mui/material"
export default function() {
  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="body1" paragraph>My styled Typography</Typography>
      // The next line can't receive any classses or modifiers, 
      // but must end up styled like the <Typography> element.
      <p>my custom user content - how can i style this like above?</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your theme.  From there you can access the body1 default typography style to apply to the p element.

```
import {Typography} from '@mui/material'
import {useTheme} from //im not exactly sure where this comes from '@mui/material' or '@mui/styles'

export default function() {

  const theme = useTheme()

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="body1" paragraph>My styled Typography</Typography>
      <p style={theme.typography.body1}>my custom user content - how can i style this like above?</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The user-content already contains `<p>` `<h1>` or other markup tags that i can't modify with React - at best i could add styles to their parent...  

Is there a way to globally make all `<p>` etc. tags inherit `theme.typography.body1` ?

Comment: How do you do this for other elements besides Typography, like the styles of a `Link` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useTheme ,Typography} from "@mui/material"
    
    export default function() {
    
      const theme = useTheme()
    
      return (
        <>
          <Typography variant="body1" paragraph>My styled Typography</Typography>
          <p style={theme.typography.body1}>my custom user content - how can i style this like above?</p>
        </>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `sx` prop in your custom component:

```
const P = styled("p")({});
```

```
const theme = useTheme()
```

```
<P sx={{ ...theme.typography.body1 }}>
```

If you want to use system properties:

```
import { unstable_extendSxProp as extendSxProp } from "@mui/system";

const Psx = styled("p")();

function P(inProps) {
  const { sx, ...other } = extendSxProp(inProps);
  return <Psx sx={sx} {...other} />;
}
```

```
<P {...theme.typography.body1}>
```

If you want to use `variant` prop like in `Typography`:

```
const T = styled('p')(({ theme, variant = 'body1' }) => ({
  ...theme.typography[variant],
}));
```

```
<T variant="h3">
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related Answer

- [Passing props to MUI styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69677803/9449426)