# When initialize javascript objects, how to add keys when required only?

Tags: javascript, syntax, javascript-objects

for example, I want to add "msg" keys only when msg is not null:

```
myFunction: function(msg){
  var jsonObj={
    "name" :"abc",
    "time" : 12345,
  };
  if(msg!==undefined){
    jsonObj["msg"]=msg;
  }
  return jsonObj;
}
```

but I don't want the if statements, is there any syntax to write something like that:

```
myFunction: function(msg){
  var jsonObj={
    "name" :"abc",
    "time" : 12345,
    msg!==null?["msg":msg]:nothing
  };
  return jsonObj;
}
```

?

Comment: if the intent is to use this for JSON (you call it jsonObj) that you will use JSON.stringify on, to actually end up with JSON, rather than a javascript object - just `msg:msg` because `undefined` values are not converted to JSON

Comment: `only when msg is not null` ... your code would only add it if it's not `undefined` rather than not `null` ... `null` !== `undefined`

Comment: what is the exact use for the object returned by myFunction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/38483660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Undefined properties are not copied.

So you can use jquery extend function

```
var jsonObj = $.extend({}, {
    msg: msg!==null ? msg : undefined,
    // and so on...
});
```

If `msg` is null, then msg attribute will not exist in `jsonObj`

In other way, using ES6 has better solution:

```
var jsonObj  = {
   ...msg!==null && {msg: msg}
}
```

Comment: `using ES6` nice!

Comment: But you will force him to use jQuery or a transpiler.

Comment: shouldn't it be undefined, not null?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default value for `msg`, then yes, it's possible:

```js
function myFunction(msg){
  var jsonObj={
    name :"abc",
    time : 12345,
    msg: (msg !== null ? msg : "msgDefault"),
  };
  return jsonObj;
}
console.log(myFunction(null));
console.log(myFunction('foo'));
```

But without a default value, it's impossible - you'd have to resort to an `if`.

Comment: You could do the trick by setting the default value of msg to undefined instead of msgDefault.

Comment: It was `null` in the example provided by the OP, so I didn't change that. (sometimes differentiating between `null` and `undefined` is important)

Comment: Returning undefined will mean that iterating the object (or possibly converting it to JSON encoded string) will skip the msg key; setting it to null will not.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete jsonObj.msg when it is undefined type:

```
var msg = undefined;
var jsonObj = {
    "name": "abc",
    "time": 12345,
    "msg": msg
};
jsonObj.msg === undefined ? delete jsonObj.msg : false;
```

jsonObj will add key named "msg" and then delete it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current answer I provide.
Just add the field you want and pick the null out when output

```js
function test(msg) {
  var jsonObj = {
    name: 'abc',
    time: 12345,
    msg
  };
  return _.omitBy(jsonObj, _.isNil);
}

console.log(test());
console.log(test(123));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49766148/edit#
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that Object.assign only "copies" enumerable properties

```js
var msg = null;
var jsonObj = {
    name: 'abc',
    time: 12345
};
Object.assign(jsonObj, Object.create({}, {msg: {value: msg, enumerable: msg !== null}}));
console.log(jsonObj);
```

> However, you call the variable in your code `jsonObj` - presumably, this object is used to send data to a server using JSON data interchange format? if so, then you can simply do

```js
var msg = null;
var jsonObj={
  "name" :"abc",
  "time" : 12345,
  "msg" : msg !== null ? msg : undefined
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 4));
```

> as `JSON.stringify` (the function that turns javascript objects into JSON) ignores any property that is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunction(msg){ 
    var jsonObj=(){ 
        this.name = "abc";
        this.time = 12345;
        msg && this.msg = msg;

        return this;
    };

    return jsonObj;
}
```

Create object inside closure. AND operation will return value of second operator if first operator is truthy.

On my phone so difficult to test if it executes as written, but that's the conceptual example.

Answer (score -2):

You can shorten your if statement.

```
if(!obj.msg) obj.msg = null;
```

Comment: Don't Know OP's requirements but this is a pattern I use when designing API's for certain use cases where I know the obj can only be undefined or truthy and then the database does the validation. So yes you can.

Comment: Well breaking down OP's obj it looks like he's building a chat API so this could work.

Comment: Also @JaromandaX what do you mean it won't work when it's `null` or `undefined`? The if statement works as expected.

Comment: Also since it's a msg it is always a string so `0` would never apply unless the user by passes the client but the server would correct it automatically as a int type is not valid string and it would fail thus triggering the if

Comment: Your right it doesn't really answer he's question it's more of a eye opener that you can design a API way more simply if you look at another pattern.

Comment: I don't get why you would assume to know that the value of msg can only be a string or anything else is considered "wrong" ... the first sentence in the body of the question is `I want to add "msg" keys only when msg is not null`

Comment: @JaromandaX OP's question is totally irrelevant and belongs in code review not here.

Comment: @JaromandaX Because `msg` implies a string. There's no in between... There's either a body to a msg or not. The fact that OP is putting `null` means he's dealing with some kind of SQL storage but what is the point of storing/communicating something that has no value?

Comment: but `jsonObj` implies the object is going to be made into JSON - so the solution is even simpler as `undefined` properties are ignored in the "stringify" process :p is my inference any less valid than yours :p

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly! So again OP needs to realize that what the hell their trying to do can be done differently and more simply!