# add key value to object conditionally javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an empty object like this

`let queryParams = {}`

I want to add some objects conditionally to this:

```
if(status){
  //add this 
  adminapproval:req.body.approvalStatus
}

if(type){
  //add this
  $or: [
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat_ws', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
                  $like: '%' + keyword + '%'
                }),
    { email: { $like: '%' + keyword + '%' } },
    { company: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
    { mobileNo: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
    { city: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
    { country: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } }
]}
```

If the two conditions are true the final object look like this:

```
{
  adminapproval:req.body.approvalStatus,  
  $or: [
    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat_ws', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
      $like: '%' + keyword + '%'
    }),
      { email: { $like: '%' + keyword + '%' } },
      { company: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
      { mobileNo: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
      { city: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
      { country: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } }
  ]
}
```

My solution  is to put this  individual object into array and build the object in aloop but I think its a bad way. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new key value pair to an object you can simply do so by assigning value object.newkey as if the object already had that key.

```
let queryParams = {};
if(/*condition*/){
    queryParams.adminapproval=req.body.approvalStatus;
}
if(/*condition2*/){
    queryParams.key1=value1;
    queryParams.key2=value2;
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
let queryParams = {
    ...status && {
        adminapproval: req.body.approvalStatus,
    },
    ...type && {
        $or: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat_ws', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), { $like: '%' + keyword + '%' }),
            { email: { $like: '%' + keyword + '%' } },
            { company: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
            { mobileNo: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
            { city: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } },
            { country: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } }
        ]
    }
}
```