# How to use webpack dev proxy with Nuxt

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, nuxt-edge

Using [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org) to develop a universal JS app, I'm attempting to configure [webpack's dev proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) so that, *in development only*, requests to `/api` get proxied to `http://127.0.0.1:500/api` where they'll reach a Python REST API. Following the Nuxt docs, I've [extended the webpack config](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/extend-webpack/) in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```
build: {
  extend (config, { isDev }) {
    // Proxy /api to Python only in dev
    if (isDev) {
      const devServer = {
        proxy: {
          '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
        }
      }
      config.devServer = devServer;
    }
  }
}
```

If I log the config, I see that change being applied:

```
...
devServer: { proxy: { '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' } } }
...
```

Yet, when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/things, my Nuxt app is returned (it runs on port 8080 in dev), indicating that the webpack dev proxy is not catching the `/api` path and performing the proxying. Just to confirm that the proxy *destination* is working, if I visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/things, I get the expected API response. **Why, when I've extended the Nuxt webpack config to enable the webpack dev proxy, does the proxy not function?**

I have, however, had success with the [@nuxt/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module) module, but critically, I could not find a way to make it only affect development and not production. That portion of `nuxt.config.js` looked like this:

```
axios: {
  proxy: true
},
proxy: {
  '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
},
```

I'm happy to use the @nuxt/proxy module instead of (on top of?) the webpack dev proxy if it can be made to work in development only.

Comment: This answer on a similar question helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990952/how-to-setup-nuxtjs-proxy-to-avoid-cors-when-connecting-with-strapi/67991061#67991061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Nuxt *needs* to proxy, even in production. When my initial request is processed and the app is server-side-rendered, any API requests need to be proxied because the Node server is doing the calling, not a browser, so those API requests won't even hit my production router like nginx or HAProxy (which typically does my routing for `/` and `/api` to the appropriate services).

Comment: But sometimes all requests are sent from the client, like submitting the form. Under such condition, proxy only in development is still necessary.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do this and was able to solve this using the following in nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // other config ...

  ...process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8000',
    }
  },
}
```

This code will only add the proxy key in the nuxt config if we're doing a development build.

Reference to the syntax used to insert the conditional object field (this was previously unknown to myself):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51200448