# Nuxt.js SPA devserver settings

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have configured devserver in vue-config.js before like this:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/api/*": {
      target: "http://localhost:3001",
      secure: false
    }
  }
}
```

In nuxt-SPA this dont work. My front is still sending API-calls to same origin localhost:3000. How to configure API-calls to different port?

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of 
[How to use webpack dev proxy with Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230470/how-to-use-webpack-dev-proxy-with-nuxt)
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/762

Due to its unversal app nature Nuxts doe not have webpack proxy.

Simpliest one to implement is here - https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module