# Babel 7 and webpack 4 not working for Conditional spread operation in Array[Short circuit syntax]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am facing peculiar problem where short circuit syntax is not working after upgrading to Babel 7 from previous version where I was using stage-0 and it was working without any issues

Do Not work:

```
...isCSCProfile && [{ isComplete: progressbarStates[3] === PROGRESS_BAR_SUCCESS, messageKey: commonOrderMessages.service_request_header, link: "serviceRequest-header" }],
```

Works:

```
...(isCSCProfile ? [{ isComplete: progressbarStates[3] === PROGRESS_BAR_SUCCESS, messageKey: commonOrderMessages.service_request_header, link: "serviceRequest-header" }] : []),
```

I have included Babel-Polyfill plugin in webpack and I am testing in latest chrome version

So question is which plugin should I include to make it work without changing the code

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `isCSCProfile` is boolean. If `isCSCProfile` is false, then you're trying to spread a boolean in the first case, <strike>which will not work</strike>.

After digging a bit more into this it seems I was wrong about spread syntax not working for booleans. [`@babel/plugin-transform-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-spread) has option named `loose`, that should just skip "nullish" values, which is what you want here. There's also an open [issue about loose mode consistency](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7327), which is very likely the reason this doesn't work right.