# Add or avoid adding a property in an object depending on a boolean within the object itself

Tags: javascript

Basically I wonder if I could avoid adding a property into an object if a variable is false but from inside the object. So let's say I have this object:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' };
```

Now I want to rewrite the same object but I only want to add the second property if a new variable, which is a boolean, is true.
The problem is how could I do this for example with a ternary operator like this:

```
var add = false;
var obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  (add ? bar: 'foo': null)
};
```

What I want to avoid is to have this:

```
...
bar: ( add ? 'foo' : undefined )
```

Because I don't want to have the bar index in case add == false. Also the assignament must be inside to object ( that's the question about, if it's posible ) because something like this is not what I'm looking for:

```
...
if (!add) delete obj.bar; // This would be after the creation of the whole object
```

**Work arounds**

Obviously this can be achieved in many ways, but I haven't found any that is done inside the object itself. I could use a ternary operator and having two objects like this:

```
var obj = add ? {
  foo: 'bar',
  bar: 'foo'
} : { foo: 'bar' };
```

But this would lead to having duplicated code ( when the object has more properties ).

**Edit** I'd say that my question is slightly different from the duplicates since my question refers to do it *inside the object* not after its declaration nor anything that isn't between `var obj = { ... }` 
There is an accepted answer but I would love if someone knows any other way of doing it without the use of **spread operator**. Thank you all

Comment: So, if it isn't there, it should return `null`?

Comment: @TylerRoper no, it simply shouldn't be there, like if you delete the property.

Comment: What is wrong with `var obj = {
  foo: 'bar', bar: (add ? 'foo' : null)
};`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it ( it terms of syntax ) but I want to avoid having the `bar` index. Because when I send the data if the `bar` index is present then it fails

Comment: Another duplicate that has slightly more discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object

Comment: @Bergi that post doens't solve my question. It's a different question....

Comment: @Osakr Bergi's answer to the marked duplicate is literally the exact same as the answer below by bugs. It definitely answers your question.

Comment: Well, I can't use spread operator in my project :(

Comment: @Osakr You should have mentioned that, as it really reduces your options. The duplicate I commented a bit ago may have more alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object  - Not to mention, the same answer that bergi provided in the marked duplicate also includes an alternative *without* the spread operator, using `Object.assign`.

Comment: @TylerRoper you're right. I would have done it if i would knew that this could be done with spread operator :D

Comment: At least I'm happy that nobody downvoted the post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way of doing it using the spread operator:

```js
const condition = false;

const foo = {
  bar: 'baz',
  ...(condition ? {
    boz: 'bat'
  } : {})
};

console.log(foo);
```

This works because the spread operator for object literals does nothing on objects without enumerable own properties.

Comment: This is strong thing :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciate. But I cannot use spread operator in my project. Anyways if nobody finds another way I will mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result , use below option of adding propeter based on condition in separate line

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ebQmrb?editors=1010

```js
var add = false;
var obj = { foo: 'bar'};
if(add){
  obj.bar = 'foo'
}

console.log(obj)
```

**Option 2:** Use undefined value for bar, if condition is false and use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to remove undefined 'bar' property on condition -false

```js
var add = false;
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ "foo": 'bar', "bar" : add? 'foo': undefined}));
console.log(obj);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zyMgxj?editors=1010

Comment: I know this, the easy solution. Anyways I'm not looking for this. What I want to know is if there is a way to achieve this but from inside the declaration of the object, not after it. Anyways thanks for your time

Comment: @Oskar, what about option 2, if you assign undefined value to bar ,  works as workaround for unavailable bar value

Comment: That way is contempled in the post and it keeps the `bar` index in the object

Comment: @Osakr, I have remove undefined bar property in my updated answer

Comment: @Osakr, hope it works :)

Comment: It does, thank you ^^

Comment: thanks @Osakr for the vote :)