# Add value to object only if not null-is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I read here that i can add a `key:value` to an `object` only if the value is not null otherwise the `key:value` will **not be there at all** :

```
   var product = {
         coverTitle:document.getElementById("coverTitle").value.length>0 ? getElementById("coverTitle").value : undefined,
..
..
```

Will print :

```
coverTitle:undefined
```

I expect to not have this key inside at all.

I read it here : [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/38483660)

answer by `Frédéric Hamidi`

When uploading to a server I do not want to write this pair at all, like they are not there.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The link you have posted is with jQuery. It will not work that way without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the property later - `undefined` key/value pairs are still kept in the object.

```
let product = {};
const value = document.getElementById("coverTitle").value;
if (value) product.coverTitle = value;
```

Alternatively, use `JSON` methods to remove `undefined` key/value pairs - costly, but it works:

```
var product = {
     coverTitle: document.getElementById("coverTitle").value.length > 0 ? document.getElementById("coverTitle").value : undefined
};

product = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I ask again - 1. so that answer is just wrong? what am I missing here? 2. I have many fields like that, is it better to just stringify it or you won't do that?

Comment: You can use that method in the object literal with a ternary operator and then stringify it at the end, that's the best practice. And no, that answer's not wrong - it just uses jQuery's `$.extend` which removes `undefined` fields, and that's not native JavaScript behaviour.

Comment: This performs the lookup `document.getElementById("coverTitle")` twice doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does @AvinKavish - but that's the OP's code not mine. I'd do it using an array and spreading, because the double lookup is quite inefficient.

Comment: @JackBashford so you would put them all in array and then simply loop over it right? ( just to understand something basic, say its not efficient, that means it takes another few fraction of seconds to do, the user will never feel it anyway, so is it that bad ? or is it just for us the programmers to feel better ? )

Comment: Yeah, I'd place all the element in a temporary array, `filter` over it, and then spread the results into an object after `map`ping into key/value pairs.

Comment: Why pay the serialize/deserialize cost when a function that just removes undefined properties is 3 lines long? `function clean(o) { for (key in o) { if (o[key] === undefined) { delete o[key]; } } }` - Or use `Object.keys` to be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally add the key later on, but you can't write it inside the object literal.

```
  const product = { }

  const value = document.getElementById("coverTitle").value

  if (value)
    product.coverTitle = value

  // or
  value && (product.coverTitle = value)
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way if you have 20 fields like that ?

Comment: No it's not, but there was a time on the web when everything was written with a library called jQuery. So it was seen as okay to give answers using that library.

Comment: So how would I change this line to be  to be jQuery ? (sorry if its a stupid question)

Comment: You have to check whether [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is installed or install it, it's about 80kb in size. Or you could use @Jack's hacky but working trick with `JSON.parse`. If you intend to send it to the server you will be `JSON.stringifying` anyway wouldn't you?