# Conditionally Add An Attribute To An Dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to add an attribute to a dictionary but only if the condition I pass in is true. For example:

```
def addSum(num):
    obj = {
             'name': "Home",
              'url': "/",
              num > 0 ? 'data': num
    }
```

Is this possible? I can't find a way to do this in python, I have only seen examples in javascript.

Comment: `obj` is a dictionary, not an object.

Comment: Can you add the javascript equivalent that you had in mind as well? What you posted is not valid js. Don't know of any similar syntax in javascript but it would be cool :)

Comment: lots of examples on here, here is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/38483660

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it with quite that syntax.  For one thing, you need Python, not Java/C.

(1) add the attribute, but set to `None`:

```
obj = {'name': "Home",
       'url': "/",
       'data': num if num > 0 else None
      }
```

(2) make it an add-on:

```
obj = {'name': "Home",
       'url': "/"}
if num > 0:
    obj['data'] = num
```

Comment: So in the first example the condition has to go after the value?

Comment: Yes.  See any tutorial on the Python ternary operator.

Comment: the 1st example will throw SyntaxError

Comment: Thanks; fixed the missing quotation mark and tested with cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 7):

```py
obj = {
    'name': 'Home',
    'url': '/',
    **({'data': num} if num > 0 else {})
}
```

:D

Answer (score 4):

Just add/check it in separate statement:

```
def addSum(num):
    obj = {
        'name': "Home",
        'url': "/"
    }
    if num > 0: obj['data'] = num
    return obj

print(addSum(3))   # {'name': 'Home', 'url': '/', 'data': 3}
print(addSum(0))   # {'name': 'Home', 'url': '/'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the dictionary without the optional element, then add it in an `if` statement

```
def addSum(num):
    obj = {
        'name': "Home",
        'url': "/"
    }
    if num > 0:
        obj['data'] = num;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just create the dictionary without the attribute, then create an if statement to add it if the condition is true:

```
def addSum(num):
    obj = {
          'name': "Home",
          'url': "/",      
    }
    if num > 0:
        obj['data'] = num

    return obj
```