# How can I add a property to an object conditionally

Tags: javascript

I have read this [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/38483660) but in my case, it doesn't work.

I have the following situation:

```
angular.forEach(vm.someData.entities, entity => {
  ...(entity.type === "section" && { entity.styleFormats = entity[`${vm.activeTab}StyleFormats`]});
  entity.content = entity[`${vm.activeTab}Content`];
  entity.stateClasses = determinateStateClasses(false);
  entity.isNew = false;
});
```

The spread operator gives me a parsing error.

Comment: So does adding property works or not?

Comment: Yes, it works... but I want to use the spread operator and it gives the parsing error

Comment: you want some leaner way for only if conditon ? or whole foreach loop?

Comment: @MilanKrstic: So... You're showing us code that works, but are asking about some other code you're not showing us that doesn't work?

Comment: @DEEPAK Just for the if condition. I know that an if in for is a bad idea but have to do it there.

Comment: @David, instead of the if statement I added  ...(entity.type === "section" && { entity.styleFormats = entity[`${vm.activeTab}StyleFormats`]}); and I get a parsing error.

Comment: @MilanKrstic: Perhaps you could update the question to indicate the exact code you're using and the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: @David, I will.

Comment: you are trying to spread a condition into a function block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the spread operator here.  That operator is used when constructing an object literal, which isn't what you're doing here.  You're simply writing a line of code in a function.

You *may* be able to use `&&` short circuiting to perform the intended operation:

```
entity.type === "section" && entity.styleFormats = entity[`${vm.activeTab}StyleFormats`];
```

But this is a little unclear.  Normally this kind of short-circuiting is used when resolving to a value, not when performing an operation.  Think of this as structurally like the difference between using the conditional operator (`?:`) vs. using an `if` block.  The former is not a drop-in substitute for the latter, they have their own uses.

In this case what you're looking to do is conditionally perform an operation within your function.  That's *exactly* what an `if` block is for:

```
if (entity.type === "section") {
    entity.styleFormats = entity[`${vm.activeTab}StyleFormats`];
}
```

Basically, don't try to write the *cleverest* code possible, write the *clearest* code possible.  There's no reason to avoid using an `if` block.

Comment: I didn't know why in my case it doesn't work thanks a lot, @David for the clarification