# check if has value, if not don't create field

Tags: typescript, operators

I have seen this somewhere but can't remember...

`user.address= data.address? data.address : ""`

instead of create an empty user.address field, I want to not create the field if the `data.address` is false

I'm using typescript.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just wrap it in a conditional?

Comment: not really, but how?  like this.....
`if (data.address) { user.address = data.address }`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: a conditional like that might work, but I know that there's another way to do it

Comment: You could assign the value to `undefined`, but then it'll still exist as a field in your object, which may not suit your needs. Alternatively you could make use of the spread operator as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560953/6262037 but it's not as idiomatic.