# Conditional Parameter addition to an Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Following is my code, in which I am trying to add `passStatus` to an object only if it has a value otherwise omit it.

I tried this one - [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object)

But seems like I am doing it wrong. Any pointers Please.

**Code -**

```
var a = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "",
  query: "simple"
};

// var newObj = Object.assign(a, a.passStatus ? {a.passStatus} : null);

var newObj = {
   ...(a.passStatus? {passStatus: a.passStatus}: {} )
}

console.log(newObj); // {} <- Getting a blank object
```

**Expected Output -**

```
If passStatus = ""

{
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  query: "simple"
}

If passStatus = "pass"

{
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "pass",
  query: "simple"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clearest way to conditionally remove a property from the object like this would be to use rest syntax followed by a possible `Object.assign`:

```js
var a = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "",
  query: "simple"
};

const { passStatus, ...newObj } = a;
if (passStatus) {
  Object.assign(newObj, { passStatus });
}

console.log(newObj);
```

You can do it in one line by destructuring a computed property name, where the property name uses the conditional operator to remove the `passStatus` property if it exists - but this is hard to understand, I wouldn't recommend it:

```js
var a = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "",
  query: "simple"
};

const { [a.passStatus ? '' : 'passStatus']: _, ...newObj } = a;
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: What is the underscore referring to ? here in - `[a.passStatus ? '' : 'passStatus']: _`. Can u please explain this a bit ..this is quite interesting and unique

Comment: The `[]` brackets indicate a computed property name. Eg `['foo' + '1']` will destructure the property `foo1`. The identifier that comes after the `:` is the variable name into which the destructured property gets stored. Here, we don't care about the variable, we just want to remove it so it isn't included in the `...newObj` rest syntax. You could name it anything you want and `console.log` its (empty) value later, if you wanted. But `_` is the convention for a variable name which isn't going to be used.

Answer (score 4):

Destructure the object (`a`) to remove the value, than use object spread to add it, if it's truthy:

```js
var a = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  query: "simple"
};

const { passStatus, ...obj } = a;

const newObj = {
  ...obj,
  ...(passStatus && { passStatus })
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shallow copy the entire object, if the new object has a falsey `passStatus` value, delete the property.

```js
const a = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "",
  query: "simple"
};

const b = {
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Simmon",
  email: "tomsimmon@gail.com",
  phone: "+36456",
  passStatus: "test",
  query: "simple"
};

const copyKeepOrRemovePassStatus = obj => {
  const newObj = { ...obj };

  if (!newObj.passStatus) {
    delete newObj.passStatus;
  }
  return newObj;
};

console.log(copyKeepOrRemovePassStatus(a));
console.log(copyKeepOrRemovePassStatus(b));
```