# How to create an object with a conditional computed property name in a one-liner using es6+?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, computed-properties

Let's say I have `data` which is an object with some keys.

I also have `context` and `contextId` which both are string, but `context` might be null or undefined.

How to created a new object that clones `data` and adds `data[context] = contextId` only to it when `context` is not null or undefined in a one-liner using es6+.

Comment: Here's the answer that I was just typing out and I couldn't find anywhere else. I don't get why this got closed. `let newData = { ...data, ...(context && { [context]: contextId })}`

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Your approach and answer above are practically the same. Flag being some boolean value, context or contextId makes not difference. Written with multiple aditional values or a single one, the approach is the same.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek There's no difference in whether the property key is computed or not, the strategy to make the property optional is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me when a question is too similar to another. I'll remember to reframe from posting next time in such cases. I just liked the one-liner for this specific case so much that I wanted to give it some attention