# JavaScript insert a new property to inline object only if condition is met

Tags: javascript, object, indexing, ecmascript-6

I'm aware with ES6 JavaScript object you can dynamically declare variables as object keys, using `[]`, for example:

`{[2 + 2]: "four!"}`

gives the output `{"4": "four!"}`

the question is, can a similar method be done in order to add an entire property, through variables etc., inline? Meaning, like suppose I have the following test object:

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 2,
    someOtherProp: 3 //only add this prop if a condition is met
}
```

is there anything I can write in the inline object for `someOtherProp`, to only have it be added to the object, if a certain condition is met? So for example (pseudocode), something like this

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 2,
    [someBool ? null : "someOtherProp: 3"] //only add this prop if a condition is met
}
```

would give the ouput (considering someBool is true), like the above, but if `someBool` is false, it would give me

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 2
}
```

??

I'm aware I can simply add a property (or delete one) to (/from) the object later, using the [] indexer, like

```
someBool && (myObj["someOtherProp"] = 3)
```

as well as make some kind of helper function for this,

but I was wondering if there was a way to do it using the inline-object notation?

Comment: Check the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560953/3082296) in the duplicate

Comment: @adiga yes that one answered it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560953/2016831 perfectly

Answer (score 6):

You could spread an object with a conditional operator.

`{}` is a neutral value.

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 2,
    ...(someBool ? {} : { someOtherProp: 3 })
}
```

Comment: That could be even shorter with `...(someBool && { someOtherProp: 3})`