# Can I add property to object only if true in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object:

```
const options = {};
```

and I want to add fields base on another object. if they false I don't want to add this key to the object.

right now I write my code like this:

```
const options = {};
if (foo.nullable) options.nullable = true;
if (foo.baz) options.baz = true;
if (foo.bar) options.bar = true;
...
```

if I write like this I get the `nullable` key anyway. no matter if is true or false and I want only if `true` the key should exist.

```
 const options = { nullable: options.nullable }
 // options = { nullable: ... }
```

So I asking is there a way to write this in better in typescript? something like:

```
 const options = { nullable && options.nullable } // should be options = {} if nullable is false. otherwise is options = { nullable: true }
```

Comment: Maybe use a ternary? `const options = nullable && options.nullable ? {nullable:true} : {}`

Comment: How your `foo` looks? Maybe try `if (foo.nullable === true)`

Comment: This has already been answerd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/38483660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I asking is there a way to write this in better in typescript?

Not really, no. What you have with the `if` statements is probably simplest.

You *could* use spread notation, like this:

```
const options = {
    ...(foo.nullable ? {nullable: true} : undefined),
    ...(foo.baz ? {baz: true} : undefined),
    ...(foo.bar ? {bar: true} : undefined),
};
```

That works because if you spread `undefined` it doesn't do anything. But I don't think I'd call it "better." :-)

If the values of your `foo` fields are **always** primitives, you could use `&&` but I wouldn't:

```
const options = {
    ...foo.nullable && {nullable: true},
    ...foo.bar && {bar: true},
    ...foo.baz && {baz: true},
};
```

But if the `foo` fields might be objects, that's not going to work, and clarity probably suffers anyway. (That "works" for primitives because if you spread a primitive, it gets converted to the equivalent object — `42` becomes `new Number(42)`, in effect — and by default the object types for primitives have no own, enumerable properties, so nothing gets spread.)