# React native - remove params if value is null or empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem on how to remove specific param that is passed as payload whenever the value is empty or null

Here is my code:

```
dispatch({
      type: 'REQUEST_DATA',
      payload: {
        cardNo: accId,
        types: dataTypes,
        accOwner: accountOwner,
      },
    });
```

Expected is: if accountOwner is empty, then accOwner param should not be passed as payload, same as the other params

Comment: Empty as in empty string (`''`), `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Javascript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
let payload = {
  cardNo: accId,
  types: dataTypes,
}
if(accountOwner)payload.accOwner =accountOwner

dispatch({
      type: 'REQUEST_DATA',
      payload,
});
```

Comment: I tried your implementation, did a minor change and it worked. Thanks