# Typescript/Javascript Conditionally Add members to object using spread op

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to conditionally add members to an object using the method [prescribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object/40560953#40560953)

Here is my code:

```js
const theobj = {
    field1: "hello",
    field2: 1,
    data: {
        datafield1: "world",
        datafield2: 2
    },
    field3: "yowzee"
};

let someobj: any;
someobj = theobj;

const test = {
    ...(someobj.field1 &&  {field1: someobj.field1}),
    ...(someobj.nofield && {nofield: "yowzee"}),
    ...(someobj.data?.datafield1 && {data: {dataField1: "woohoo"}}),
    ...(someobj.data?.datafield2 && {data: {datafield2: "hooahh"}}), // overwrites the above   
};

console.log(test);
```

This works great except that the last conditional overwrites data.datafield1.  Its as if it re-creates the inner data objects.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's happening exactly what you're thinking, this is why you need a reference from a previous value of the data object.

```
const test = {
    ...(someobj.field1 &&  { field1: someobj.field1 }),
    ...(someobj.nofield && { nofield: "yowzee" }),
    ...(someobj.data.datafield1 && { data: { dataField1: "woohoo" }}),
    ...(someobj.data.datafield2 && { data: { ...someobj.data, datafield2: "hooahh" }}), // doesn't overwrites the above.
};
```

By spreading someobj.data inside of itself, you are ensuring that it has his previous value.

Comment: Laian,  That worked  perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, mate

Answer (score 1):

In that last line, you're setting the `data` property of the object to a new object, `{datafield2: "hooahh"}`.

That would be the equivalent of:

```js
{
  data: { a: 1 }
  data: { b: 2 }
}
```

duplicate keys are overriden, so it becomes

```js
{
  data: { b: 2 }
}
```

---

If you want to set `data` to a single object with conditional sub-keys of its own, you can do:

```js
const test = {
    ...(someobj.field1 &&  {field1: someobj.field1}),
    ...(someobj.nofield && {nofield: "yowzee"}),
    ...(someobj.data && {data: {
        ...(someobj.data.datafield1 && {dataField1: "woohoo"}),
        ...(someobj.data.datafield2 && {dataField2: "hooahh"}),
    }}),
};
```