# If statement within return

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I add an if statement in a `return` statement of this sort:

```
return {
    ID: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media'),
    if (ID) {
        media: select('core').getMedia( ID )
    }
};
```

Clearly, I can't just drop an if statement `if ()` directly within `return {}`.

Comment: You *cannot* use `if` there whatever you do. It's never going to be valid. You can either use `if` outside or try and do something different.

Comment: A better way to ask this is, how can I dynamically add a property to a literal object?

Comment: @JuanMendes What is the answer to that?

Comment: `return { ID: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media'),
 ...(ID ? {media: select('core').getMedia( ID )} : {}) }`

Comment: @JuanMendes Please post as an answer.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson There's an example already [on the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396398/227299) which was used to close this question as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do, either use a ternary operator inline:

```
return {
    ID: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media'),
    media: (ID ? select('core').getMedia( ID ) : undefined)
};
```

or create the object and conditionally add a new property

```
const obj = {
    ID: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media')
};

if(ID){
    obj.media = select('core').getMedia( ID )
}

return obj
```

Comment: I guess `ID` is the property. You want `if(obj.ID){`.

Comment: This adds the `media` property when not needed

Comment: @JuanMendes The first one adds a property with the the value `undefined` this may or may not be a problem which is why I included the second options

Comment: @jabaa that doesnt make any sense. `ID` as far as I can tell is just a variable set elsewhere

Comment: Why would you call `select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media')` if the ID already exists in a variable? If the `ID` already exists, you can create `const obj = { ID };`.

Comment: I have seen this question asked and adding an undefined is pretty easy. The complicated thing is not adding the property, in one shot. See my comment to the answer

Comment: @jabaa "*Why would you call select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media') if the ID already exists in a variable?*" does it? It is not at all clear from OP's code. Nor is there an explanation for what `ID` *variable* contains and if it overlaps at all with the `ID` *property*. We could guess or we could avoid guessing and work with what is provided by OP.