# Sending in a prop object where some are dependant on a boolean value without addition object creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component taking in the prop `data`.

```
<Button
    data={booleanValue && {
        d: 4,
        // another 8 key/values
    }}
/>
```

So data value only gets passed in if `booleanValue` is true.

But I also have another 3 more value which I wish to add inside this data which are meant to always show.
So show irregardless of whether booleanValue is true or false.

Is there a way I could write this elegantly within the component above itself?

I could create the object separately like following which would work.
But trying to see if I could achieve it without additional object creation.

One possible solution but don't want to create an object like this.

```
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
};

if (booleanValue) {
    obj['d'] = 4;
    // more values being added same way.
}

<Button
    data={obj}
/>
```

Attempted the following but it doesn't capture the keys a,b,c.

```
<Button
    data={{
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
    } && booleanValue && {
        d: 4,
        // more values being added same way.
    }}
/>
```

Possible solutions mentioned here.
[In JavaScript, how to conditionally add a member to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object)

But I can't spread as per the answers considering I am adding the a,b,c values in the component itself.

 And other answers in here involves adding an object first.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is separate props.

```js
<Button a={1} b={2} c={3} d={booleanValue && 4} />

// or
<Button data={{a:1,b:2,c:3}} optionalData={booleanValue && {d:4}} />
```

But, if you need to keep a single `data` prop.

```js
<Button
  data={{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    ...booleanValue ? { d: 4 } : undefined,

  }}
/>
```