# How to configure docusaurus config keys conditionally?

Tags: conditional-statements, config, docusaurus

If a user needs to configure an optional docusaurus config key based on some condition, what is the best way to address it in docusaurus.config.js file?  For example:

```
module.exports = {
  /* If condition is true then */
  showLastUpdateAuthor: true,
  /* otherwise set it to false */
  //Other config key value...

}
```

Here is what I tried and it worked.  Is there a better way to handle this?
Insights via Spread Syntax discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704267/in-javascript-how-to-conditionally-add-a-member-to-an-object).

```
const branch = require('child_process')
  .execSync('git branch --show-current')
  .toString().trim();

module.exports = {
    ...(branch != 'main') ? {showLastUpdateAuthor: true,}:{showLastUpdateAuthor: false,},
    //Other config key value...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Any other better way?

```
const branch = require('child_process')
  .execSync('git branch --show-current')
  .toString().trim();

module.exports = {
    ...(branch != 'main') ? {showLastUpdateAuthor: true,}:{showLastUpdateAuthor: false,},
    //Other config key value...
}
```