# Instead of Document.all, what can I use?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm calling a javascript for my Gridview, but it seems like document.all does not work in Chrome/Firefox.

What can I replace this with?
Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    GridViewHelper.Init(document.all.GridView1, 100, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: looks like a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy

Comment: `document.all` hasn't been a good choice since IE 4 stopped being a common install. You need to find some more up to date learning resources.

Answer (score 4):

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) is the usual choice (the element needs an id).

There are plenty of other options though, including the new, shiny and less well supported [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector).