# renderable "type trait" in typescript react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I guess I'm still a C++ programmer at heart. I was just spinning up a very simple helper class to clean up some debug UI:

```
const MaybeIfValue: React.FC<{text: string, value: any}> = ({text, value}) => {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return null;
    }
    if (value === null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{text}</span>{value}<br/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

...and I was thinking, I really don't want `any` value here. Not that it's going to matter *here* in practice, this is a one off helper function. But plenty of times in development over the years I've accidentally tried to render something complex. I'm still only moderately experienced with Typescript, so I don't quite know the right term for it, but what I'm wondering about, is how do I `static_assert` that the compile-time typeof value is renderable? I'd call it a type trait in C++. What's the term in typescript? Matching?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: updated example to constrain generic `T` by [`ReactChild`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1c0d34eff93e70c289fb4207174e8bfd0f37b0d4/types/react/index.d.ts#L233) after seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70514178/438273).

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you want a strongly-typed component function.

Here's a link to the [functions page in the TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), specifically the section which addresses overload signatures, which is what I'm using in the snippet below to provide multiple call signatures, each with it's own [return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) that depends on the type of `props.value`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGhLMoGEALYHJG0imAURxRBQB2MAL5w0UCCDgByKHRjSA3AChlaLAMrAIAuAFkMATwBGKAJJoAahhxYUcABRgJYAgC5EcGCgAeMDwQwUMACAOaKcABuNnYA-B4CuDhwAD5wGqhoIShIcMIAlAlJKuqaMNq6BibmVjH2ADwAKnC+3gJIRBwMzKwAfE4u7p7efgFBIeFRdR7NBR5d3Lz8QiUaWjr6RqYW1rb2Dggj1FN7wh4IXq1jwWER0Xvx6QIA1gIQAO66BYjKcHByMCwUF0DnudjgAF4oXBEjhkik0mD7FCIU9MtkkPk4LEYUk4B4HL8-nB6khgJFekTiSSCGAMAJeodWsJ6gB6Wn0xlIlnGKCsynUtlkilE-IqYQqZRVba1PYHI4eaSMFBwiDSb6s1m4uFSrY1XZ2eVXGTK1XSGhIopwjVa2E4XXVHZ1I2jE0qnBqi3TNHoDE27X2h0yg0oF3+N1mr17DyYHAEFAagBUVOpqbT6epAD1s9nlFwoBIoDNDGB7NJjBAILx6dI4MAiG98AQCMBQgIMMZeF4IF4S2WFkwWEhpAA6BwAJgA7AA2ACcWMTrNU0v1zqZrqV7s9JzsHgAjOP-QseHxBDAg6u5evw5vIzuUIrTR71VjNbROCflue3ygYOQRwBQA)

```ts
import {default as React, ReactChild, ReactElement} from 'react';

function MaybeIfValue (props: { text: string; value?: null | undefined }): null;
function MaybeIfValue <T extends ReactChild>(props: { text: string; value: T }): ReactElement;
function MaybeIfValue ({text, value}: { text: string; value?: unknown }) {
  return (value === null || value === undefined) ? null : (
    <div>
      <span>{text}</span>{value}<br/>
    </div>
  );
};

MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello'}) // null
MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello', value: null}) // null
MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello', value: undefined}) // null

MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello', value: false}) /*
                             ^^^^^
Error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactChild'.(2769) */

MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello', value: 12}) // ReactElement
MaybeIfValue({text: 'hello', value: 'hello'}) // ReactElement
// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is simply "type". And avoiding the `any` is a very good practice, since it drops *all* type checking.

`ReactNode` is technically the type for something renderable, but it's a bit [too permissive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840095/62076) since it seems to allow objects and functions.

`ReactChild` is the type you want, I believe. It is the type of "something renderable", that can typically just be dropped into a pair of `{}`.

```
import React, { ReactChild } from 'react'

const MaybeIfValue: React.FC<{text: string, value: ReactChild}> = ({text, value}) => {
  //...
}
```

Tests:

```
// Works
const goodStr = <MaybeIfValue text='good' value='foo' />
const goodNum = <MaybeIfValue text='good' value={123} />
const goodJsx = <MaybeIfValue text='good' value={<>Foo</>} />

// type errors
const badObj = <MaybeIfValue text='good' value={{ obj: true }} />
const badFn = <MaybeIfValue text='good' value={() => null} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gFkUBPAIyQElMA1FAGwFckALkTEYAOgBiAYQA8AbxhIAHjBF0owKgHMANHABufQSOToJZjNIAWwXgBMAvgD44AXjgAKRSpj6jAkiOAJTurvKkcFFwwJheAYLubh78VPZImFpI9qER0flwRDD8UFRwVPy8vADckdGOdVGx8cZISR4VVbmNBUUlZZ01PQ35faVePfmy9sAGzpMFUbI0YChUzj6qjrIA9CtrGwlBsixQO-OLSzszcz3BtQ2kOztwAOrQANY0FNR0cNoQCD2ADKMCg7jgskYrA43FacCUqjc+ABQPwhlayMwgPR5x+tHgqPsADl+HgPFDmGxODxAgjfMiieijm55ABGABMAGZHHA8ZQCf9AfYAFI0ZQQykwmnwxEwRnC5mY+SyZySQG7Zy8vFPF4wJhgNpIKA4KDfAV-FgoewAeRYACtJdDqXC6XKFWiMYFWfI4BAHSIwYlHNr5hb4Fb7JIyhTnbDaYl3SjFV7BKzPKE3K5BqGgA)

---

Also, quick tip, *the one time* you're allowed to use `==` instead of `===` is for comparisons to `null`, which which be truthy for both `null` and `undefined`. It saves a lot of lines of code.

I, too, have a line much like this at the top of many of my own components.

```
if (value == null) return null
```

Comment: [`(document.all == null) === true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#loose_equality_using_) also

Comment: TIL, [and I am kind of horrified.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy) Though if you're passing `document.all` as a prop to a react component, you got bigger problems.