# Is document.all an object or a function?

Tags: javascript

The title is the question. (Do not mention functions being objects that are callable; it is not the conventional categorization.)

Comment: document.all is an ancient Internet Explorer function returning  an htmlcollection, later added to some other browsers like [chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all) and deprecated

Comment: [here is an interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy/62005426)

Comment: "*(Do not mention functions being objects that are callable; it is not the conventional categorization.)*" then what categorisation do you want to use here?

Comment: "*Do not mention functions being objects that are callable*" - why not? Since you already know this, is your actual question whether `document.all` is callable? You should be able to find out by simple trial-and-error.

Comment: @VLAZ I prefer the more common-place distinction between `function` and `object` types that does not have one being a superset of the other.

Comment: @Bergi See [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72587327/1953537#comment128236019_72587327) I made prior to this one.

Answer (score 1):

`.all` is a property of the document (or prototype), and that property is a getter that returns a function. In other words, referencing the `.all` property invokes the getter (which is one function), and then the getter gives you another function. This behavior is [specified here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-all) (but is way obsolete, and not something you should ever see nowadays).

For example, in Chrome, you can see that the property is a getter in the following:

```js
console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'all')
);
```

and that the value returned is callable by calling it:

```js
document.all();
```

The value returned by the getter is an HTMLAllCollection.

It doesn't inherit from `Function.prototype`, so it's not a *normal* function - it's an exotic object - but it [does have a [[Call]] internal method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlallcollection) and so is callable and can be called a function. (and functions are also objects, of course, as you know)

Comment: "*you can see this in the following*" - I can only see that the `.all` getter is a function, not that the `HTMLAllCollection` it will return is callable

Comment: So, would a good correction of `typeof value` be to return `"function"` if `typeof value === "undefined"` and `value !== undefined`?

Comment: @Melab Yes, it would return `"function"` if it wasn't special-cased [for reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10350142/1048572).